# Passing values from UIButton to an UIActionSheet

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to send an ActionSheet a variable from a button.

I can't use the tag property because its being used for something else.

I've declared myIndexRow as an instance variable and have:

```
NSInteger myIndexRow = indexPath.row;
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDeleteSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    deleteButton.myIndexRow = myIndexRow;
```

but I'm getting the 'Request for member 'myRow' is something not a structure or union'

There  is something obvious I am missing here.

Comment: The above failed.  See answer below for a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never figured I'd answer my own question on SO but here goes:

Accessing the superview's superview and querying the indexPath section and row properties did the trick.

In the target of the button:

```
-(void)showDeleteSheet:(id)sender {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];

    NSInteger currentSection = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger currentIndexRow = indexPath.row;

    //form the actionSheet
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete this item?" 
                                                         delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];                         
    actionSheet.tag = currentIndexRow;
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];
}
```

Then down in the actionSheet's clickedButtonAtIndex method I get the row I need:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

     if (buttonIndex == 0)
        { ... doSomethingWith: actionSheet.tag }
     else
        { ... user pressed cancel }
}
```

Part of the answer was found [in another post and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview) and the rest [here](http://www.71squared.com/2008/12/custom-button-in-uitableviewcell-indexpath/)