# How to get indexPath.row/path When I click the Switch in a row?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I create tow or more custom cell

each cell has a switch inside

How can I know which switch in the row I click

ex.I click the switch in row 3,than It will return indexPath.row = 3

and also the switch status is on or off ?

which void I should put in ?

I know there is a way can get indexpath return by:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

But I don't want to touch the row,just the switch ...

Oh I do some research but it just be a little different

[How can keep track of the index path of a button in a tableview cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863940/how-can-keep-track-of-the-index-path-of-a-button-in-a-tableview-cell)

any ideas ?

I wish I can post my screen shot,but not I am a new user 
the system doesn't allow me to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the switch, set up a target and action for it:

```
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Here, the target `self` is your `UITableViewController`, in which you'll need to implement the method `(void) switchToggled:(id)sender` to handle the control event. The switch will automatically send itself to the `switchToggled` method as the `sender` when it is toggled. Like this (modified from the `UIButton` example you linked):

```
- (void)switchToggled:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if(theSwitch.on) {
      // switch turned on
    }
    else {
      // switch turned off
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm..It looks can be work!I try it now !
Thanks !How can I be a good programmer like you ?

Comment: Excuse me,I create a LightCell0;and a TableViewController,I
have to put this code in which one ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919616/uitableviewcell-indexpath-crash-in-ios7 for iOS7. There are additional wrappers for table views and cells. I had to use:     
`UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)switchControl.superview.superview;

UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview;`

Answer (score 1):

When button is created

```
button.tag = [indexPath row]
```

When button is selected, pull the row out of the tag

```
int myRow = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
```

Comment: Can I put this in [lightSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchlightswitch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged] ???