# Program Crash when I click a switch?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiswitch

Here is my old question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620148/how-to-get-indexpath-row-path-when-i-click-the-switch-in-a-row)

I ask a question before,But I put the answer in my code It can compiler without error

But when I click the switch ，the program crash

I just want to click the switch ,than return which row I click

Here is my code

First I create a `LightTableViewController.h/.m`

Than I create `LightCell0.h/.m`

in `LightCell0.h`

```
@interface LightCell0 : UITableViewCell { 
 UILabel     *lightLocation;
 UIImageView *lightImageView;
 UISwitch    *lightSwitch;   
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lightLocation;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *lightImageView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UISwitch *lightSwitch;

- (void)switchlightswitch:(id)sender;
```

I need each cell will be an image ,Textlabel ,switch inside

In `LightCell.m`

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
 if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
  lightLocation = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  lightLocation.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
  lightLocation.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
  lightLocation.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  lightLocation.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];

  lightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

  lightSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];

  [self.contentView addSubview:lightLocation];
  [self.contentView addSubview:lightImageView];
  [self.contentView addSubview:lightSwitch];

  [lightSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchlightswitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

  // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}
```

- (void)switchlightswitch:(id)sender{

```
 if (lightSwitch.on){
  lightImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lightOn.png"];
 }
 else {
  lightImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lightOff.png"];
```

}
}

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

 [super layoutSubviews];
 CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
 CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
 CGRect frame;
 frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+10 ,0, 44, 44);
 lightImageView.frame = frame;
 frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+60 ,3, 150, 44);
 lightLocation.frame = frame;
 frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+220, 10,0,0);
 lightSwitch.frame = frame ;

}
```

So far,the program can response when i change the switch status ,it will also change the image.

but if I put this code in ,i can compiler ,than crash if I touch any switch

`[lightSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]`;

and give a void

```
- (void)switchToggled:(id)sender {
 UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if(theSwitch.on) {
  NSLog(@"You Switch On the NodeID:%i ",indexPath.row);
    }
    else {
  NSLog(@"You Switch Off the NodeID:%i ",indexPath.row);
    }
}
```

the crash message is "`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[LightCell0 indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`"

does anyone knows what's going on with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, I suspect your cast is wrong:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview;
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
```

Are you sure that the superview of theSwitch is a UITableViewCell and the super view of the cell is the UITableView. The crash tell you that the tableView object that you respect is a LightCell0 object

Comment: I'm not sure .......Because I just reference the answer and directly copy into my code....

Comment: Vodkhang is correct, your logic/design is wrong at some point. The 'superview' of the 'superview' of the switch is your cell and not the tableview as you expect

Comment: that's not my answer...just someone tell me this can be work...so I copy his answer.

Comment: so, that answer doesn't work. Why do you need to get the indexPath? For what purpose

Comment: I think you need to do theSwitch.superView.superView.superView , 3 times, try with that

Comment: sorry,Vodkhang...can you write a sample code for me ?I  really don't understand how to do...I stuck here almost one day...

Comment: The sample code that I suggest is : theSwitch.superView.superView.superView

Comment: Cool It won't crash  But no return back "NSLog(@"You Switch On the NodeID:%i ",indexPath.row);" I will try some breakpoint

Comment: What is the output of the NSLog, anything?

Comment: I click the switch ,Nothing return but the image  change function is fine

Comment: You mean nothing in the console, did you set breakpoint in `    if(theSwitch.on) {
  NSLog(@"You Switch On the NodeID:%i ",indexPath.row);
    }
    else {
  NSLog(@"You Switch Off the NodeID:%i ",indexPath.row);
    }`. Does the runtime call either if or else?

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake,I forget to remove the mark,The void was not call,so the program wont crash,after I remove the mark,the program crash again.

Comment: reason :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewControllerWrapperView indexPathForCell:]and "Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”."

Comment: uhm, so it is not correct, this approach to call superview is just wrong:(

Comment: it is ok, you can send me your file, I don't have XCode here but will try to do code inspection for you. `vodkhang@gmail.com`

Comment: yes You give a right answer :UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview; ->UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview.superView;

Answer (score 0):

For getting the status of the switch, you are using "yourSwitch.on", which I don't think is correct.
Chang it to `[yourSwitch isOn]` and test your app.
I see 2 statements in your code where you are checking the state of a switch. Change them and try.

Comment: but still don't know to get which switch I click ?

Comment: Why not give the switch a tag and create a new NSIndexPath based on the tag:

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer!
theSwitch.superview actually returns the contentView inside UITableViewCell.
So you should change to:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview.superview;
```