# Custom Cell Button tag always return zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am in trouble with an issue for a couple of days now . The issue is i have a table with multiple custom table cell and each cell has multiple buttons . But i am always getting the tags value as zero. Below is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CuatomCell_Contacts *cell    =   (CuatomCell_Contacts *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellA"];
    if  (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects            =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CuatomCell_Contacts" owner:Nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if  ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell =  (CuatomCell_Contacts *) currentObject;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    IstructContacts *ObjIstructContacts = nil;
    if (table == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        ObjIstructContacts = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        ObjIstructContacts = [self.sectionedListContent objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    cell.m_CtrlLblName.text = ObjIstructContacts.m_strName;
    //cell.m_CtrlLblContact_Id.text=ObjIstructContacts.m_strContact_Id;
    NSLog(@"%@",ObjIstructContacts.m_strImageUrl);
    if ([ObjIstructContacts.m_strImageUrl isEqualToString:@"No_image"])
    {
        cell.m_CtrlImgImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Person_Dumy.jpeg"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: ObjIstructContacts.m_strImageUrl]];

        cell.m_CtrlImgImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    }
    cell.M_CtrlBtnChat.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.M_CtrlBtnChat addTarget:self action:@selector(MoveToNextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(MoveToNextView:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0f, 5.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f);
    button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}



-(void)MoveToNextView:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSLog(@"Tag Value = %d",button.tag);
}
```

Tag value always returns Zero .. In both static and dynamic button actions.

Comment: how many rows are there in your table view section?

Comment: check indexPath.row if its returning what your are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Set tag with section also like bellow

```
cell.M_CtrlBtnChat.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]intValue];
```

if you have more then 1 section and in every section you have 1 row then may be you get 0 for all rows so get value of section also like above code..

**For EX:** If you want to get row number as a tag to button then you assigned that with its `indexPath.row` and you get `0` every time but if you set it with section then you get it like `00`,`10`,`20`,etc.. **If you have a multiple section and in every section you have only one row.**

**Update:** Also now set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to different value and check it out. like bellow...

```
NSString *cellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section:%d Row:%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
CuatomCell_Contacts *cell    =   (CuatomCell_Contacts *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
```

Comment: @ParasJoshi what will be the tag value for the button on the index [11,2] and [1,12] ,In this way it will be 112 for the tag in button ,How indexpath can be identified?

Comment: yes that is right but here he asked that button tag get 0 everytime so i post this first check it out that here he get different tag or not .. now whats the problem i just want to find out it.. :)

Comment: @Vishnu now i update answer try it out also yesterday i update my answer on you previous question which you ask here?? you try that??

Answer (score 3):

Try this method, cleaner way to find view's enclosing row.

```
 -(IBAction)cellButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    CGPoint correctedPoint = [button convertPoint:button.bounds.origin toView:self.tableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:correctedPoint];
    NSLog(@"Button tapped in row %d",indexPath.row);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost worked for me, but in the end I used the cell, rather than the button, with `NSIndexPath *indexPath=[tableView indexPathForCell:cell];indexPath.row;`

Answer (score 2):

I tried out a sample project and it works fine for me like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"CustomCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell*)[array objectAtIndex:0];
       }

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(MoveToNextView:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0f, 5.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f);
    button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}
-(void)MoveToNextView:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSLog(@"Tag Value = %d",button.tag);
}
```

and on button click my log shows

```
2013-07-23 11:58:31.719 Trial[895:11303] Tag Value = 0
2013-07-23 11:58:33.726 Trial[895:11303] Tag Value = 1
2013-07-23 11:58:35.126 Trial[895:11303] Tag Value = 2
2013-07-23 11:58:35.998 Trial[895:11303] Tag Value = 3
2013-07-23 11:58:36.910 Trial[895:11303] Tag Value = 4
```

Comment: hey i post this type of answer on this Question see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785855/button-inside-a-custom-uitableviewcell-not-working/17786750?noredirect=1#comment25945506_17786750 :)

Answer (score -3):

You have initialized a button in a wrong way

Instead your code as below,

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(MoveToNextView:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0f, 5.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f);
button.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Please try with my following code

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton alloc]init];
 button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(MoveToNextView:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0f, 5.0f, 150.0f, 30.0f);
button.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: allocating button to [[UIButton alloc] init] only to overwrite that object with a new object does nothing but waste clock cycles.

Comment: @cncool: tag is depended on the initialization & declaration of the control it owns. And I've also experienced the same problem, which I solved using the initialization only.First let the questioner try this solution. @ Lithu T.V first one is wrong by that I meant that for tag  he has to initialize the button though it is initialised explicitly using custom type