# How can I keep track of selected row of a button in a table view cell?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

Similar to this, 
[How can I keep track of the index path of a button in a table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863940/how-can-i-keep-track-of-the-index-path-of-a-button-in-a-table-view-cell)

Do we have **any way we can select the row index of a **NSTableView**** when clicking on the button in the table cell.

Comment: Resolved : 1. Created a outlet for button. 2. Added the tags to it dynamically. 3. In action get the sender tag which is nothing but row index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement below delegate method in this you can identify which cell you have selected:-

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(id)cell
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
              row:(NSInteger)row
```