# NSIndexPath for UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to implement the block method outlined in the answer to the question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863940/how-can-i-keep-track-of-the-index-path-of-a-button-in-a-table-view-cell/15922961#15922961), but I don't understand how to set the block. Assuming that...

```
 cell.onButtonTapped = ^{
        [self buttonSelectedAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
```

is pseudo code, how would I actually implement this assuming I have a `UITableViewCell` (not a custom cell) and a `UIButton` within that cell. Is it possible to do this without creating my own `UITableViewCell` subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're gonna do it this way, you'd really have to make a UITableViewCell subclass which is a target of its button, has a property for the block and calls the block when the button is tapped.

There's actually a simple way to know from which indexPath a subview (eg. the button here) of a cell is from. First you'll need a point on the tableView's coordinates, which is contained by the subview. Let's say you'll choose the center of the subview. To convert it to the tableView's coordinates:

```
CGPoint subViewCenter = [self.tableView convertPoint:subview.center fromView:subView.superView]; // because a view's center is on its superview's coordinates
```

to get the indexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:subViewCenter];
```

Answer (score -2):

No, as per the answer you are referring to, you need a custom UITableViewCell.  Essentially you are calling a method on the cell and passing the current indexPath for that cell.

Whether you use the block method or the delegate method you will need a custom UITableViewCell as you need somewhere to store the indexPath and a method to set it.