# How to send next responder from custom button on tableviewcell to UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiresponder

UPDATE:

i have MENUViewController and i insert this view to TableViewCell, when i press button on MENUViewController how to pass nextResponder to TableViewCell ?

from LOG at my button in MENUViewController class->NSLog(@"nextResponder = %@", self.nextResponder); 
it show like this?

```
2010-07-22 02:14:12.627 NewsReaderV2[3576:207] button Press
2010-07-22 02:14:12.653 NewsReaderV2[3576:207] nextResponder = <UITableViewCell: 0x5f33120; frame = (0 48; 320 129); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x5f330d0>>
2010-07-22 02:14:13.987 NewsReaderV2[3576:207] button Press
2010-07-22 02:14:13.988 NewsReaderV2[3576:207] nextResponder = <UITableViewCell: 0x5f3a490; frame = (0 177; 320 129); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x5f3a570>>
2010-07-22 02:14:18.019 NewsReaderV2[3576:207] button Press
2010-07-22 02:14:18.020 NewsReaderV2[3576:207] nextResponder = <UITableViewCell: 0x692b210; frame = (0 306; 320 129); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6925480>>
```

@END of UPDATE

i have insert button on each cell ,when i press on that button it will not send message to

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

how to make responder from button send message to UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select corresponding cell when button in it clicked - determine cell's indexpath in click handler (see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview/1802875)). Then call `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method on your table view.

Comment: if my Button are in another class can you give me some advise?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you can't do exactly? Handle button click, select tableView cell or something else...

Comment: Solution in the link I've posted should work for your case as well (see solution in Edit2) - you convert touch point to table view's coordinate and get nsindexpath using tableview's indexPathForRowAtPoint: method. All you need is have a reference to your tableview of course to call this methods and assign proper action to the button (that takes UIEvent paramater)