# Passing a value on a IBAction button method in a UITableview Row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a value called member id and I want to send it to another view controller, If I place the following in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, The value passes to the variable "member".

```
int memberIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    member = [[tableDataSource2 objectAtIndex: memberIndex] objectForKey:@"Memberid"];
```

If it is placed in the cellForRow, of course it rewrites with every row created. I have a button in each row that launches a viewController, I want the button action to grab the rows "member" and pass it to the new controller. Is there a "didSelectButton at index path method" or a way to grab that on the fly?

any Ideas would be great. It's the first time I'm adding a button to a UiTableview.

Thanks

Comment: See this question (and answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview/1802875#1802875

Comment: @ Vladimir  Thanks I used this link, works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the accessory view?  It is a built-in button that you can skin with any image you want to give the UI any kind of feel that is required.  Then add this to the table's delegate:

```
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{ ... }
```

You will then be able to call your method on your table data source and launch your secondary view.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? The documentation on this method clearly states "This method is not called when an accessory view is set for the row at indexPath. " Indeed, in my case the method does not get called if I set a custom button as the accessory view.

Answer (score 0):

Just play with "tag".

Each UIView has an attribute tag (int).

in the cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
//create yourButton and then
yourButton.tag = memberIndex;
```

and when you are using an IBAction just get the sender :

```
- (IBAction) didSelectButton:(id)sender
{
int memberIndex = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
//
}
```

tips : to get the sender when you are setting the action property of your button don't forget the ":"

E.G

```
action = @selector(didSelectButton:);
```