# how can I take index of particular row by clicking a button(targeting to method)?

Tags: iphone, indexing, cell, uitableview

I have made a table and contents some values, I have a button coding like

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIButton *btn=[UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(290, 15, 15, 15)];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(editTable:) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:btn];

NSString *cellValue = [myArrayNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
```

I want to click that button and take values from that particular index,

like

Ali             (button here) --------index 0
Sajid           (button here) --------index 1
Robert          (button here) --------index 2
RaM             (button here) --------index 3

Theser are cells of table, now how can I get index as I click that button?

if you are not getting my question, you can ask me again...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer,

Just write the following coding inside the button targeted method and use clickButtonPath as your index path.
It is working perfectly, simply

```
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then in `(void)editTable:(id)sender`:

```
int row = (UIButton *)btn.tag;
```

Comment: but if it is saving one value in btn, then not removing it, even I am clicking other buttons, now what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

you would use something like this.

```
- (IBAction)editTable:(UIButton *)sender {
   UIView *contentView = [sender superView];
   UITableViewCell *cell = [contentView superView];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

But first you should make sure to properly reuse your cells. By changing your code like this:

```
cell = ... dequeue cell ...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = ... create new cell ...
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.tag = 194;
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(290, 15, 15, 15)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(editTable:) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
}
// if you need to change something for this button you can get it like this:
//UIButton *btn= [cell.contentView viewWithTag:194];
NSString *cellValue = [myArrayNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
```

Comment: Error here "'*** -[UIButton superView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x393a5c0'"