# Set up a UICollectionView delete button in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building an app that uses a collection view to display data that can be deleted by users.

In the prototype cell, I created a button that now appears in every cell that is created (a small X). How can I set the button up to tell me which cell should be deleted (like indexPath.row)?

In principle, I want to do something like this, but in Swift: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761086/correctly-grab-the-indexpath-row-of-a-uibutton-in-custom-table-cell)

> I'd be grateful for any help! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(123, 123, 40, 40)];
    [myButton setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellDeleteBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteCellFromButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:myButton];
    return cell;
}

- (void)deleteCellFromButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [myMutableArray deleteItemAtIndex:button.tag];
    [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Here is a Swift version:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var myButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(123, 123, 40, 40))
    myButton.setTitle("X", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
    myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageNamed("cellDeleteBtn.png"), forState: UIControlStateNormal)
    myButton.setTag(indexPath.row)
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: "deleteCellFromButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
    cell.addSubview(myButton)
    return cell
}

func deleteCellFromButton(button: UIButton) {
    myMutableArray.deleteItemAtIndex(button.tag)
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Sorry only saw now it's swift. Updated the title

Comment: I'm not sure how to set up indexPath.row

Comment: What do you mean you dont know how to set it up. At which point do you struggle then we can explain it further from there.

Comment: I get an error when I create an outlet from my button: The outlet is invalid because of repeating content (i.e. It appears in every cell)

Comment: Since I can't create an outlet, the above methods don't work

Comment: Well initialize the button inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. `UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];`. Did you do it this way?

Comment: I used a StoryBoard to create it, but I found a way to tag it

Comment: Well dont, add it programmatically and use it programmatically. Just add the CollectionView in storyboard. See my updated answer.

Comment: I added a link to the question to another post which has a similar problem but I don't understand the Objective-C

Comment: Update my ObjC to Swift and just try it? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87255/discussion-between-emotality-and-gjz).

Answer (score 0):

```
serviceView.collectionArray.removeAtIndex(path.row)
serviceView.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([path])
```

Comment: The button does not have an indexPath.row as it is available in every cell

Comment: Then tag the button with indexPath.row ?

Comment: I updated my ObjC answer, might help to do it yourself in Swift. :)