# How to delete a UICollectionViewCell via UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Okay so I'm trying to make a "-" button delete a UICollectionViewCell, but I can't seem to find anything that can help me out, I'm just a beginner. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm also using core data

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32068382/3687801)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up a UICollectionView delete button in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068216/set-up-a-uicollectionview-delete-button-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

you just remove your data of data array and do `tableView.reloadData()`. May as below.

```
dataArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.reloadData()
```