# uitableview touch event

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a button inside of `UITableViewCell`, and when I click a button ,I want go to author view control with index value.

```
 tapped  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[tapped setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
[tapped setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSInteger tet;

tet = indexPath.row; 
[tapped addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];

[Cell addSubview:tapped];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

You should tag a button with indexPath.row.

```
tapped.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Inside your event handling code, you should use that tag to find index.

```
-(void) tapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    int index = btn.tag;
    //Do rest...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(void) tapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    int section = indexPath.section;
    // You get easily your index path row
    int row = indexPath.row;
    // push your controller 

}
```

first update ur code

use ur event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

```
tapped  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[tapped setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
[tapped setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSInteger tet;

tet = indexPath.row; 
[tapped addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[Cell addSubview:tapped];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can tag the button as follows :

```
tapped.tag = indexPath.row
```

And in the the tapped method You can use it as follows:

```
-(IBAction)tapped:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
int index = btn.tag;

}
```

use this index as per your requirement...