# Buttons for each row UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell in a UITableView, defined by a custom class (.h and .m files). I am able to display the cell, and change the text for each cell in the list, but my custom cell also has buttons in it (two, actually). When I click the button, I need to know which row's button has been clicked. Is there any way to get this within the custom ui cell class?

I hope what I'm requesting is clear. If not, feel free to comment and I'll try to explain as best as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

1. Set an associated object value with each button. You can support this by adding a category to UIButton

   ```
   @interface UIButton (AssociatedObject)
   @property ( nonatomic, retain ) id associatedObject ;
   @end
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
   @implementation UIButton (AssociatedObject)

   -(void)setAssociatedObject:(id)object
   {
       objc_setAssociatedObject( self, @"_associatedObject", object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC ) ;
   }

   -(id)associatedObject
   {
       return objc_getAssociatedObject( self, @"_associatedObject" ) ;
   }

   @end
   ```

   Use this like this:

   ```
   myButton.associatedObject = <some object>
   ```
2. Set action/target to your view controller (or maybe table view delegate)

   ```
   [ myButton addTarget:<view controller> action:@selector( buttonTapped: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ] ;
   ```
3. In your action, look at the sender's associated object. Sender will be your UIButton

   ```
   -(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton*)sender
   {
       // retrieve object associated with the tapped button:
       id associatedObject = sender.associatedObject ;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You don't show any code to comment on, but generally speaking you can:

1. define a `tag` for each button which represents the table row where the button appears;
2. when your button action method is called, you can access then the `tag` property of the button to know which row it was.

   ```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
          if (cell == nil) {
            ...
          }
          ...
          [button setTag:indexPath.row];
          ...
      }


      - (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
      {
          UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
          int row = button.tag;
      }
   ```

For a more elaborate solution, have a look at [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview).

Comment: Thanks, will try and get back to you. :)

Comment: This solution won't work if user can insert/delete/reorder rows in the table without reloading data.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by creating a `protocol` for the custom cell class and then making the `UIViewController` that is handling the `UITableView` the `delegate` for each of the custom cells.

Then I attached the `UIButton` to an `IBAction` in the custom cell class that made a call to it's delegate with information about which cell it is or which information I needed to act on.

So I would set up a `protocol` with something like:

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) cellButtonPressed:(NSDictionary *)stuffForDelegate;

@end
```

Then when I implemented `cellButtonPressed:` in the `ViewController` I would use `stuffForDelegate` to determine which cell it was or what information I needed to act on.

The `tag` method is okay, but I find it tedious to deal with all of the tags flying around and I prefer using objects and protocols and delegates instead.