# didSelectRowAtIndexPath UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

I have a UIButton added to a UITableViewCell
I want this button to call the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" I already know about calling

```
  [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
```

but the problem that I can't get the indexpath and tried the

```
[self.Tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:[self.view convertPoint:[sender center] fromView:self.Tableview]]
```

method but it returns the same CGPoint , Any help ?

Comment: indexPathForRowAtPoint:point returns indexPath, where do you get CGPoint from?

Comment: I get it from the button CGPoint point = [sender center];

Comment: you need to convert point to tableView's coordinate system (or get the point from UIEvent as described in Edit2 in my answer in dup question

Comment: How to convert to TableView's coordinate system ?

Comment: Using convertPoint:toView: method. But I'd stick with UIEvent/UITouch approach

Comment: convertPoint:toView: still doesn't work , I ended using tags but want to know what is wrong

Comment: Show code that does not work? SO does not encourage long comment threads so if you consider that worth discussion either edit your post and put your code in it

Answer (score 4):

First, you should not directly call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` yourself. It is a delegate method, and the table view should call it.

Instead, make a separate method to do what you want to do, and call that from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Second, you can get the index path like this:

```
UIButton* button = (UIButton*) sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)button.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

This works because if everything is set up the standard way, the superview of the button should be the cell's `contentView`, and that should be a subview of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do according to me is give **ROW NUMBER AS TAG VALUE FOR tableViewCell' button**,
so when you click **button** its action will be called from which you will get the **sender id** sender_id is nothing but UIButton instance, fetch its tag value..

eg: You have UIButton *testButton;
    Its Selector is @selector (testButtonPressed:)

So when tableViewCell's Button is pressed it will call @selector (testButtonPressed:)

```
-(void)testButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"index is %d", sender. tag);
 }
```

Comment: This is not very scalable e.g. it only works for one section.

Comment: @Paul.s Yes, but you could set up a scheme like `tag = section*1000+row`.

Comment: @Mundi I just generally am not fond of the `tag` property there are better ways of doing things - like your answer for example

Comment: i think its scalable... coz tag is being set when u create cells.... this logic can improved... by having custom button (meant to say inherit button class) and have variable of type NSObject which can be used as tag.... so using this method we can even send tag object as paramter for actions