# Select UITableView's row when clicking on UISwitch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a `UITableView` with `UISwitchs` on them.

[image: TableView]

When the switch is toggled I want to run a function. The function just logs If the switch is on or off and the row that the switch has been changed on. The problem that im having is that when I click on the switch it does not log the correct row unless I have clicked on that row before clicking the switch.

I guess my problem is that clicking the switch does not select the row. How can I make it so that it either selects the row or can I add the ID to the switch?

So switch ID "1" is "ON".

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"POICell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    //set the cell text to the catName
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.catNames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    //add switch 
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = switchView;
    [switchView setOn:YES animated:NO];

    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged: ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

     - (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
            NSString *StrCatID =[[NSString alloc]init];
            StrCatID = [self.catIDs objectAtIndex:[self.inputTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
            UISwitch* switchControl = sender;
            NSLog( @"The switch for item %@ is %@",StrCatID, switchControl.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF" );
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To find the cell that holds the switch**

```
UISwitch *switchInCell = (UISwitch *)sender;
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*) swithInCell.superview;
```

**To find the indexpath of that cell**

```
NSIndexPath * indexpath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]
```

In your case

```
 - (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {

         UISwitch *switchInCell = (UISwitch *)sender;
         UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*) swithInCell.superview;
         NSIndexPath * indexpath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]
         NSString *strCatID =[[NSString alloc]init];
         strCatID = [self.catIDs objectAtIndex:indexpath];
         NSLog( @"The switch for item %@ is %@",StrCatID, switchInCell.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF" );
        }
```

Comment: In iOS7, the superview will be a UITableViewCellContentView, which is wrapped in a UITableViewCellScrollView. You could instead get the index path of the cell by using the following: CGPoint switchPositionPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:[self tableView]];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:switchPositionPoint];

Answer (score 9):

You should set the `IndexPath.row` as a Tag to each `Switch` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method

```
 switchView.tag= indexPath.row;
```

And when switch value change .you'll get the Row number

```
- (void) switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {
  int rowIndex =[sender tag];
  //rowIndex you may use it further as you wanted.
```

}

Comment: I think this is by far the best approach.  The other approaches of looking up the view hierarchy and even worse, translating a point to a view, feel hackish and like alot of work.  The only trouble you might run into with this solution is if you have multiple sections, but that can be solved by making the tag encode both section and row.  Something like this:  switchView.tag = indexPath.section * 1000 + indexPath.row;

Answer (score 8):

You can retrieve the NSIndexPath for the UISwitch that was changed in the tableview. This is the same idea for any control as already answered in this post : [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender 
{
    CGPoint switchPositionPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:[self tableView]];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:switchPositionPoint];
}
```

This will work for iOS7, previously I used [sender superview] but that now returns a  UITableViewCellContentView inside of a UITableViewCellScrollView.

Answer (score 5):

I had to do double `mySwitch.superview.superview` to get the proper cell.

Here's an example

```
- (void)switchToggle:(UISwitch *)mySwitch
{

 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)mySwitch.superview.superview;
 NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
 NSLog(@"toggle section %d rowID %d", indexpath.section, indexpath.row);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, and all of your cell has the same id.

Comment: If I use [self.inputTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row Id gives me  the row selected.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is determine which cell the sender is in.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)findCellForView:(UIView *)view
{
    for (; view != nil; view = view.superview)
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            return view;
    return nil;
}
```

Once you have this method. then it's a matter of replacing `[self.inputTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` with

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self findCellForView:sender];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.inputTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;

@end


@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arr;
    UITableViewCell* aCell;
    UISwitch *myswitch;
}


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arr;
    UITableViewCell* aCell;
    UISwitch *myswitch;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [arr count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    aCell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SwitchCell"];

    if( aCell == nil )
      {
        aCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SwitchCell"];
        aCell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        myswitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        aCell.accessoryView = myswitch;
        [myswitch setOn:YES animated:YES];

       }
    switch (indexPath.row)

    {
        case 0:
        {
            [myswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            [myswitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
            break;

    }
    return aCell;
}

- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *aswitch = sender;

    if (aswitch.on==YES) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"hello" message:@"okfine" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"no1" message:@"notfine" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Returnback" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }

}
- (void) switchChanged1:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *aswitch1 = sender;

    if (aswitch1.on==YES) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"second" message:@"okfine" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"no2" message:@"notfine" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Returnback" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
  }


- (void)dealloc {
    [tableview release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Refrain from posting code-only answers. Please add an explanation to it.

Comment: Adding a bunch of code to a year old post without an explanation isn't really helpful. Please explain so other that see this might be helped