# How to code an UITableView with a Switch like the Alarm App iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to code a `TableView` like the alarm view on the Alarm App on iOS7. The view displays the alarms and the user turns ON and turns OFF the alarms with a switch.

I have 2 views : a `TableView` controller to display the alarms and a `View` controller to setup a new alarm. When the user taps on the ADD button on the View Controller, it adds the new alarm with a switch on the `TableView`.

I have an `NSObject` : "XYZAlarm" which contains 2 `NSString` : alarm and descriptiveText.
I have an `NSMutableArray` : "Alarms" declared in the .h file of the `TableViewController`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    XYZAlarm *alarm = [self.alarms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = alarm.itemName;
    UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    return cell;
}
```

I will store the alarms with `NSUserDefaults`.
I'm a little bit lost concerning the switch. How can I code the switch function to enable or disable the alarms ? And how to store the state of each switch ?

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121139/select-uitableviews-row-when-clicking-on-uiswitch). Thanks everybody !

Comment: The question here and the question is is claimed to be a duplicate of are two difference questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heart of the problem is knowing when the switch changes and *which row* the switch was in. You must give each switch an action method for its `valueChanged` so that you can learn when the user moves the switch. But how will you know which row's switch this is? Here's how I like to do it:

```
UIView* v = sender; // sender is the switch sending `valueChanged`
do {
    v = v.superview;
} while (![v isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]);
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)v;
NSIndexPath* ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Now you know the index path (section and row) for the cell that is the superview of the switch that was changed. So now you can store this change in your model.

Be sure to set the switch's state *every* time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, because the cells are reused.

Answer (score 0):

XYZAlarm needs another property, a BOOL, which is used to store whatever your switch means. When you configure the cell, set the switch's `on` property to the value in the new property on XYZAlarm. When you switch the switch, update the property of the appropriate alarm object.