# Get IndexPath from a UITableViewCell's subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

here is my situation, I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a subview of my custom `UITableViewCell`, I set recognizer's target to my tableviewcontroller, so I want to know how can I get this cell's indexPath from my tableviewcontroller's action method.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)recognizerAction:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = sender;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
        YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)recognizer.view;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [self doSomethingWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Comment: i think `recognizer.view` is subview of my cell, i should get `MyCustomCell` from [view superview], thank you a lot anyway.