# UIButton tag not being set correctly in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my `UITableViewCell` I have a `UIButton` which represents a phone that when the user touches is suppose to call the phone number specified with the specific object in the table cell.
[image]

Since I will have multiple buttons and each button will have a specific phone number I am trying to set the `tag` property on the `UIButton` to the current `indexPath.row`, however it works for the first 6 cells but when the cells start being reused the tag just goes back to 0 for all the buttons.  I am setting the button's tag outside of the reuse block which I thought should be the proper way to do this in order to identify each unique cell.

For testing, I also set the `cell.tag` property to the `indexPath.row` and it works perfectly, so it certainly is isolated to the UIButton. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SchoolCellIdentifer = @"SchoolCellIdentifier";

    SchoolInfoItem *item = [self.schoolArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SchoolCellIdentifer];


    // If the cell doesn't existing go ahead and make it fresh.
    if (cell == nil)
    {        
        // Begin Phone button view
        UIButton *phoneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(67, 70, 35, 35)];
        phoneButton.tag = 80;
        UIImageView *phoneView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phone-icon.png"]];
        phoneView.frame = CGRectMake(2.5, 2.5, 30, 30);
        [phoneButton addSubview:phoneView];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:phoneButton];

    }

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    phoneButton = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:80];
    [phoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callPhoneNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    phoneButton.tag = cell.tag;
    NSLog(@"phoneButton tag: %d", phoneButton.tag);
    NSLog(@"cell tag:%d", cell.tag);

return cell
}
```

Here is the method for the TouchEvent:

```
- (void) callPhoneNumber:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    SchoolInfoItem *schoolItem = [self.schoolArray objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    NSLog(@"tag at: %d", button.tag);

    if ([schoolItem.MainPhone length] != 0)
    {
        NSString *URLString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:schoolItem.MainPhone];
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
        NSLog(@"%@", URL);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop setting cell-dependant things like tags in the nil check part of a control statement, it is *always* wrong when making TableView cells.  Consider how dequeueing works, not so much the logic of cell initialization and you'll see why.

Comment: Your problem is with this line `phoneButton = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:80];` where the variable `phoneButton` isn't actually being set on re-use because its tag is not going to always be 80. I recommend using the answer where you subclass `UITableViewCell` though as that is a much better approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags really aren't the right way to handle this.  You'd be best to subclass UITableViewCell with a attribute of MyPerson.  **[Note: Replace Person with School if that is appropriate]** Like this:

```
@interface MyPerson : NSObject
@property (...) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (...) NSString *emailAddress;
@end

@interface MyPersonCell : UITableViewCell
@property (readwrite) MyPerson *person;
- (IBAction) callPhoneNumber;
- (IBAction) sendEmail;
@end
```

Then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation you configure the cell as

```
cell.person = [get person from datasource for section+row];
```

Additionally, the UIButton actions link to the cell itself (as implied by the code above) or to the table view controller itself.

If you use Xcode storyboards you'll want to use 'prototype cells', configure with `MyPersonCell`, add a `UIButton` and link the button action to the cell.

Comment: My app wasn't using StoryBoards or prototype cells and I wasn't in the position to change it's functionality, although this was pretty useful and got me thinking of ways to do a similar situation. I ended up sub classing my `UIButton` with a property on it called schoolIndex which I then set from the `indexPath.row`.  Then in my method selector I just accessed the property and it seems to work fine.  Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of dealing with this (instead of using tags), is whenever a button is pressed, handle it like shown on the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802875/250164

Datasource should indeed consist of Person objects, as suggestion by GoZoner.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (cell == nil)
{        
    // Begin Phone button view
    UIButton *phoneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(67, 70, 35, 35)];
    phoneButton.tag =indexpath.row; // try it ..
    UIImageView *phoneView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phone-icon.png"]];
    phoneView.frame = CGRectMake(2.5, 2.5, 30, 30);
    [phoneButton addSubview:phoneView];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:phoneButton];

}

cell.tag = indexPath.row;

[phoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callPhoneNumber:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


NSLog(@"tag is :%d", phoneButton.tag);

 return cell
```

Try this code i edit in your code . i hope this code useful for you.