# How to push a view from custom UITableViewCell with button action (with parameters)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I added a button on the custom cell. It pushes a view. I created property for button on CustomTableViewCell.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *selectedMapButton;
```

I want to use selectedMapButton for push a view on TableViewController.m
I tried this code, but something is not right.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cord = cellSight[@"S_Coodinates"];

    [cell.selectedMapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sightMapButton:cord) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //When I call sightMapButton method. It gives an error

    return cell;
}

- (void)sightMapButton: (NSString *)withCoordinates
{
    TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController *mapKitController = [[TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController alloc] init];
    mapKitController.sightCoordinates = withCoordinates;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapKitController animated:YES];
}
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: do you want to call method from perticular button of perticular cell.?

Comment: my button on the custom cell, but I must call in Tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify your own parameters to button action handler. Its variant with 1 parameter will accept "sender", that is button that triggered the action. Your workflow should be following:

1. Find indexPath of cell where button was clicked
2. Get cellSight object corresponding to that indexPath
3. Fill your controller with info from cellSite object.

(somewhat pseudo-)Code may look like, assuming you have array of SiteObjects:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = ...  // create/init cell somehow

    [cell.selectedMapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sightMapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)sightMapButton: (UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = ... // Find indexPath of button
    SiteObject cellSight = sitesArray[indexPath.row];
    TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController *mapKitController = [[TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController alloc] init];
    mapKitController.sightCoordinates = cellSight[@"S_Coodinates"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapKitController animated:YES];
}
```

How to find indexPath of cell containing button you can find for example [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802875/137350)

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.selectedMapButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.selectedMapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sightMapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (void)sightMapButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController *mapKitController = [[TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController alloc] init];
    mapKitController.sightCoordinate = self.sights[sender.tag][@"S_Coordinates"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapKitController animated:YES];
}

Comment: I tried this and this also work. Sorry for disorder.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate way with delegate/protocol (my best way);

`-` Create a "CustomCellDelegate" class. (base class is NSObject)
 `-` Open CustomCellDelegate.h and add this code;

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
   - (void) uiTapButtonWithParameter:(NSString *)parameter;    
@end
```

`-` Close CustomCellDelegate.h
 `-` Open CustomCell.h and add this code;

```
#import "CustomCellDelegate"

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic) id <CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
```

`-` Close CustomCell.h
 `-` Open CustomCell.m and add code inside to UIButton action method;

```
[_delegate uiTapButtonWithParameter:@"hello world!"];
```

`-` Close CustomCell.m
 `-` Open CustomViewController.h and add this code;

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource, CategoryItemsCellDelegate>
```

`-` Close CustomViewController.h and open CustomViewController.m
 `-` Add this code;

```
- ( NSInteger )tableView:( UITableView * )tableView numberOfRowsInSection:( NSInteger    )section; {
    return 20;
}

- ( UITableViewCell * )tableView:( UITableView * )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:( NSIndexPath * )indexPath; {

  CategoryItemsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

  cell.delegate = self;

  return cell;
}

- (void) uiTapButtonWithParameter:(NSString *)parameter{
     NSLog(@"%@",parameter)
 }
```

Mert kardeşim delegate ve protocol en doğru çözüm olacaktır ;)

Answer (score 1):

in your custom cell class add `action` for button and define a protocol(Delegate) invoke the delegate method from button action. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the `delegate` of your cell to `self` and implement the delegate method.
let me know if you've any query.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in @selector(sightMapButton:cord) which is used to retrieve method's address. Most likely you are not allowed to pass arguments here.

As an alternative to finding the indexPath of cell where button was clicked:
You can subclass UIButton and add required information to it as a property. Then you can go the way Vladimir suggested, and get your cord from sender after casting it to your Button class.

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir's answer works correctly and I tried this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.selectedMapButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.selectedMapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sightMapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)sightMapButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController *mapKitController = [[TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController alloc] init];
    mapKitController.sightCoordinate = self.sights[sender.tag][@"S_Coordinates"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapKitController animated:YES];
}
```

It is also works.

Answer (score 0):

- We can use blocks to get cellIndexPath .
- Instead of using CellDelegate to call button actions Blocks will be
  the better option .

> @interface WACustomCell : UITableViewCell
>
> ```
> @property(readwrite,copy)void (^cellCallBackMethod)(NSInteger rowIndexPath);
>
> -(IBAction)buttonTappedFromCell:(id)sender;
>
> @end
> ```

```
 @implementation WACustomCell

 @synthesize cellCallBackMethod;


     -(IBAction)buttonTappedFromCell:(id)sender{

 self.cellCallBackMethod(0);

 //any value can be given as we will retrive this value from CellForRowAtIndex method


 }
```

In View Controller

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


cel = ....
cell.cellCallBackMethod = ^(NSInteger cellIndex){

    [self cellButtonTappedFromCellWithIndex:cellIndex];
};

return cell;
}
-(void)cellButtonTappedFromCellWithIndex:(NSInteger )cellIndex{


SiteObject cellSight = sitesArray[cellIndex];
TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController *mapKitController = [[TOCGSightseeingMapKitViewController alloc] init];
mapKitController.sightCoordinates = cellSight[@"S_Coodinates"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapKitController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add the method in Custom table view cell.

Comment: but it must to take coordinates from TableviewController