# Custom UIButtons in UITableViewCell (need to determine row)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

Each cell in my UITableView contains a custom UIButton. I can't seem to detect in which cell the currently pressed button lies. Method gets called but indexPath.row is always 0. Any suggestions?

```
-(IBAction)editButtonTouch:(id)sender {
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
   switch([indexPath row]) {
       case 0:
           NSLog(@"first row");
           break;
       case 1:
           NSLog(@"second row");
           break;
   }
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Make editButtonTouch detect which row the user currently touched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
```

actually needs to be

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
```

But a better way of doing this is illustrated here: [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview#answer-1802875)

Comment: (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]; didn't work (indexPath still always 0). Will check out the linked thread.

Comment: ok, so i modified this answer by removing one superview call (leaving only two) and it worked! Thanks @marosoaie :)