# IOS how to access element inside a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I can access the the layer of the cell and update it background by this code:

```
if(cell.layer.sublayers.count < 3){
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topGold.CGColor, (id)bottomSilver.CGColor, nil];
        [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

But i dunno how to access the sub -UIView (title) contained inside the cell (cardCell), because I want to update the background of the view (title) background by layer too

[image]

Comment: Give the label a tag. Then you can easily reference it.

Comment: that is not a label, that is a UIView

Comment: Still the same. Works with any view.

Comment: This might help too http://stackoverflow.com/a/35281457/210171

Answer (score -1):

You can simply iterate through the subviews of the cardCell.contentView to find the Title subview

```
NSArray *subviews = cell.contentView.subviews;

if ([subviews count] == 0) return; 

for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
   if (subview.tag == 5) {
    // do something
    NSLog(@"%@", subview);
   }


}
```

Comment: You can't access the subview from the cell's layer. You want `NSArray *subviews = cell.contentView.subviews;`.

Comment: I would also tag the UIView that you want to access in the story board, and then inside the for loop you can use an if statement, when you reach that UIView `if(subview.tag == 5){  //Do something }`

Comment: BTW - what good is it to iterate though all the subviews? How would you know which subview is the title? Just use tags and eliminate the looping.

Comment: there is error with this line of code NSArray *subviews = [cell.layer.sublayers subviews];

Comment: Now replace all of that code with one line: `UIView *desiredSubview = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];`