# How to get the indexpath.row when a UIImageView in a cell is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

[swift: how to get the indexpath.row when a button in a cell is tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped)

This link is an answer for when a button is tapped, and if my question is not possible I'll just use a button and put the image on it. I was just wondering if it is possible to this with tapping a `UIImageView` instead of a button. I tried the exact answer with a `UIImageView` instead of a `UIButton` and I got this error

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

`cell.imagePosted` is a `UIImageView`

```
let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
cell.imagePosted.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.imagePosted.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR);

func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{
    if let imgView = img as? UIImageView {

        if let superView = imgView.superview {

            if let cell = superView.superview as? CellCustom {

                indexPath2 = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

            }      
       }       
   }

   print(indexPath2.row)       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help you,

add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `UIImageView`
You can store `indexpath.row` in tag property of `UIImageView`  and access that tag on `UITapGestureRecognizer` event

for example (Objective-C) :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and get `indexpath.row`

```
-(void)handleImageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    UIView* view = gestureRecognizer.view;
    CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:view];
    NSInteger indexpath = [view hitTest:loc withEvent:nil].tag;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexpath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol with a method like `imageViewInCellTapped(cell:YourCellType)`and a delegate property in the cell. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the controller the delegate of each cell and implement the method from the protocol. When something happens in your cell like a button or image is tapped you can call `delegate?.imageViewInCellTapped(self)` where self is the cell then in your controller where this method is implemented you get the index using `indexPathForCell` method of the tableView.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lucian, but Madan's answer worked for me, and also I'm a beginner and I'm not familiar with protocols yet. The tutorial I did on Udemy didn't mention protocols for some reason.

Comment: You need be aware of cell reuse, you could end up with the wrong value for the indexPath if the cell is reused.

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example of cell reuse? So I would know not to do it.

Comment: A cell is reused automatically while scrolling, you can use prepareForReuse in a cell to reset its state.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Madan's code in swift if anybody is interested:

```
    func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    var view: UIView!
    var loc: CGPoint!
    view = gestureRecognizer.view
    loc = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(view)

    var indexPath: NSInteger!

    indexPath = (view.hitTest(loc, withEvent: nil)?.tag)!

    print(indexPath)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps to get indexpath for tapped cell swift 3:

```
  func nameTapped(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    var pointVAlue = CGPoint()
    pointVAlue = sender.location(in: infoTable)

    var indexPath = IndexPath()
    indexPath = infoTable.indexPathForRow(at: pointVAlue)!

    print(indexPath.row)

   /* if indexPath != nil {

        let userEnt  = ratingArray.object(at: indexPath.row)as! RateEntity

        let detailVc = AssociateDetailViewController()          

        if ((userEnt.userId as String).isEmpty == false )
        {
            detailVc.m_otherUserId = userEnt.userId as String
            self.navController!.pushViewController(detailVc, animated: true)
        }
    }*/

}
```