# Passing indexpath tag to button inside prototype cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, tableview

I have created a tableview prototype cell in storyboard and I have added a button to cell and set its tag to indexpath.row. When I scroll my cells the scrolled cell on the top of tableview always set tag to zero instead of correct tag.

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("autoLoadReuseIndentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        print("indexpath :\(indexPath.row)")


        cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100)?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        let tempDict : NSDictionary = savedCardsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary


        let bankName = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel

        deleteButton = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(106) as? UIButton
        deleteButton?.tag = indexPath.row
        deleteButton?.addTarget(self, action: "deleteCard1:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        print("delete button:\(deleteButton)")
       // print("indexpath delete tag :\(deleteButton.tag)")
        if(self.isSetUpAutoloadSelected){
            deleteButton?.hidden = true
        }else{
            deleteButton?.hidden = false
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Whenever I scroll the cells, delete button tag is always set to zero.

Comment: which view has tag 100, 102 and 106. name each view please.

Comment: Show log of `print("delete button:\(deleteButton)")`

Comment: Repeat after me "Don't use tags.  They are brittle.  They will cause me more problems than they will solve".  Use proper `UITableViewCell` subclasses with properties to reference your views.  Use a protocol and delegation to get button events from cells back to your view controller.  Have the cell pass itself to the delegate so that the view controller can identify the row

Comment: And @Paulw11 is right, btw have you created custom `UITableViewCell` class and assigned it to the cell?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/38941510#38941510 for an example of using  a protocol from cell to view controller.  Another answer on that question shows how to use closures, which is another good approach

Comment: Consider that you can create multiple custom prototype cells with IBOutlets (AFAIR since Xcode 6).

Comment: If you should go with other way then use follow code.     

    func deleteCard1(_ sender:deleteCard) {
         let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPointZero, to:self.tableView)
         let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
     }

Answer (score 1):

If you should go with other way so use follow code and get indexPath.

```
func deleteCard1(_ sender:deleteCard) {
     let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPointZero, to:self.tableView)
     let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you don't need to follow this approach because firstly you set button tag statically in storyboard and again you are change it's tag in       cellforrowatindexpath so when you scroll, cell will never find button with tag 106.If you want to follow this approach then you need to create customButton and add Variable of type NSInteger or whatever you want and store indexpath.row into that variable of customButton.
2. Another Approach is Create CustomTableViewCell Class and create button outlet in this custom Cell class and set indexpath.row into button tag like this

   CustomCellClassObject.buttonName.tag = indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

As Sumit said, it’s better to use a custom cell and create outlet for the buttons and labels, as fetching sub views using tags will be tough to maintain the code in the future.

Additionally, you don’t have to create the variable deleteButton, as I don’t see a valid purpose.

Assign tag to the button and add target in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it should work fine.