# iOS swift UIImageView change image in tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a strange problem in `tableView` Custom `cell`. for like Image action I write these code in Custom `cell` called `FeedViewCell`:

```
self.like.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let CommenttapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(likehandleTap))
self.like.addGestureRecognizer(CommenttapGestureRecognizer)

func likehandleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if self.like.image == UIImage(named: "like-btn-inactive") {

        self.like.image = UIImage(named: "like-btn-active")

    } else {
        self.like.image = UIImage(named: "like-btn-inactive")
    }
}
```

and TableViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedViewCell

    return cell
}
```

but as you see in [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8744173/quickcast-23-07-1395-01-02-13.mp4) video when I touch the like button in index 0 and change the image, the like button in index 3 change image also. can you guys tell me my mistake please?

thanks

Comment: You should have take button and give image to it. You can easily manage this thing with button. If you want answer then I will post

Comment: dear @Jecky the problem still exist with button, nothing change

Comment: I will post my Answer just try it

Comment: I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049590/reusing-cell-doesnt-work-well-tableview/40050084#40050084

Comment: Yes. The difference is only that I have a button and you have an image. It is something about reusing cells.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zedbmuqsmynx5zn/Untitled.mov?dl=0 @MohammadReza You want like this?

Comment: Ok, I will post my answer

Comment: Cells are reused, so you can't rely on the cell to store state.  You need to store liked/unliked state in your data model somewhere and then use that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and in your button handler; you should also use delegation or a closure to allow the tableview controller to handle the tap rather than having the logic in the cell

Comment: @Paulw11, you can help me with code also in my question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049590/reusing-cell-doesnt-work-well-tableview/40050084#40050084

Comment: @Jecky yes I want something like that. thanks

Comment: @MohammadReza check my answer

Comment: @MohammadReza got your answer ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya no the problem still exist :(

Comment: @MohammadReza try Jecky answer its work perfectly i try it and i got a the result so you also try it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try code its working 100%**

```
  var selectindex : Int?
  var selectedindex : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
  @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LikeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let like: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton)
        let comment: UIButton = (cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton)
        if selectedindex.containsObject(indexPath.row) {
                like.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "like.png"), forState: .Normal)
        }else{
                like.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "like (1).png"), forState: .Normal)
        }
       comment.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "chat.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        like.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CloseMethod(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        comment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.CloseMethod1(_:event:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        return cell

    }



 @IBAction func CloseMethod(sender: UIButton, event: AnyObject) {

        let touches = event.allTouches()!
        let touch = touches.first!
        let currentTouchPosition = touch.locationInView(self.tableview)
        let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForRowAtPoint(currentTouchPosition)!
        selectindex = indexPath.row
        if selectedindex.containsObject(selectindex!) {
            selectedindex.removeObject(selectindex!)
        }else{
              selectedindex.addObject(selectindex!)
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d5gzw4ocqgprfj4/AAAdRCEFv1iToXxwbDGuerWta?dl=0

Comment: I try your code yesterday brother, but I have a new problem with your code, it happened when tableView.reloadData called. see video here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8744173/quickcast-24-07-1395-03-43-51.mp4

Comment: right now i create one demo so howz its possible that you try my code ?

Comment: you send me yesterday, remember? but I try this code now and the new problem (tableview jump) is still exist

Comment: No its right now running on my pc and i dont get any problem . send me your whole project i did changes in your this code and run this project in mine pc and i again send it to you

Comment: @MohammadReza you have mine email id ? so send it

Comment: it happened (tableview jumping) because UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Did you watch my video that i comment above ? and why you use UITableViewAutomaticDimension animation ?

Comment: yes I watched, you code works fine except tableView jump problem, I use UITableViewAutomaticDimension because my cell height not static and it change depend on content height

Comment: @MohammadReza try once just comment that line and run your project with my code and check it and approve my answer brother .

Answer (score 0):

Take one array

```
let arr : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

And in tableview take button instead of image and set unlike image in button and set your images instead of my images

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let btn = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UIButton
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.connected(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    func connected(sender: UIButton){
        let buttonposition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tblview)
        let index = self.tblview.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonposition)

        if !arr.containsObject((index?.row)!) {
            arr.addObject((index?.row)!)
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_check.png"), forState: .Normal)
        }else
        {
            arr.removeObject((index?.row)!)
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_uncheck.png"), forState: .Normal)
        }

    }
```

Comment: An `IndexSet` is a better structure than an array for this task

Comment: Also, you should use a delegate or a closure to get the action from the cell rather than setting an action handler between classes  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/38941510#38941510

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. Thank you I will try it @Paulw11

Comment: @MohammadReza Download demo from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/4d3dva6rxsic6u6/Demo%20in%20Swift%202.0.zip?dl=0

Comment: @MohammadReza Got it or not ?

Comment: @Jecky yes thanks, but your code have a problem like my code!! see here : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8744173/quickcast-24-07-1395-03-03-30.mp4

Comment: @Jecky do you have an idea why on my simulator work like that?

Answer (score 0):

That's why you are changing the image loaded in the `imageView` and then with method `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` you are reusing that cell with the changed image.

In iOS `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` apply the concept of **reusable cells**. They don't create one cell for every element of the array; they just create 3-4 cells and then they'll reuse it just changing the content inside. That's a great thing because it allows developers to create tables with hundreds of rows without having memory issues.

These are the steps followed by the `tableView` (and also `collectionView`) to show the array of elements:

1. prepareForReuse
2. cellForRowAtIndexPath
3. willDisplayCell

To solve your problem you have just to check the like in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedViewCell

    let model = arrayOfElements[indexPath.row]
    if model.isLiked {
        cell.like.image == UIImage(named: "like-btn-active")
    } else {
        cell.like.image == UIImage(named: "like-btn-active")
    }

    return cell
}
```