# Only One RadioButton is Selectable for a Column Group in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, radio-group

Before asking this question I googled a lot but not able to find suitable answer.

I'm have a `UITableView` with `n` number of Columns. 
The thing is the Column is Grouped according to a key. So my UITableView header is splitted into two, one for the `column group` and and this column group is divided to show `columns`.
I have created a custom class for the `cell` there I display `radio button` in each column.

**Code:**

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GridTableViewCell *cell = nil; // My custom class for cell

    CGFloat startX = 230;

    if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[GridTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle1:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell" withRows:[self.rowHeaderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

       for (int i = 0; i < [self.groupColumNmeArray count]; i++) { // groupColumNmeArray contains the Column Group name

       NSArray *values = [_subColumnDict objectForKey:[self.groupColumNmeArray objectAtIndex:i]]; // subColumnDict contains the value for each column 

       self.originalDataArray = [CustomTableHeaderParser parseColumnInfo:values];// Parsing the values array for getting column name, type, width etc

       for (CustomTableColumn *column in self.originalDataArray)
       {

           switch (column.columnType) // acc. to column type display the cell with values.
           {
               case RadioBtn:
               {

                   _btTemp = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, 2, subCellWidth , 40)];

                   [_btTemp setTag:indexPath.row];//indexPath.row];
                   [_btTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonsClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                   [_btTemp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   [_btTemp setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   _btTemp.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];

                   [self.radioButtons addObject:_btTemp];

                   [cell addSubview:_btTemp];

               }
                   break;

           startX += 2+subCellWidth;
        }
    }
}

cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
cell.selectedBackgroundView.opaque = YES;

return cell;

}
```

Radio button click action method;

```
-(IBAction) radioButtonsClicked:(UIButton *) sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {

        [sender setSelected: NO];
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        [sender setSelected: YES];
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    NSLog(@"BUTTON TAG  %ld",(long)sender.tag);
}
```

So I'm able to make selections for radio buttons in all column but actually what I want is ***For each column group only one radio button is selectable***.

Can anybody help me. Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: Did you want to perform like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049590/reusing-cell-doesnt-work-well-tableview/40058046#40058046

Comment: No.. for me button selection/ deselection works fine but what i want is say if one of my columnGroup has three sub column so i created buttons in each subcell but i only want to select a single button under that column group

Comment: in your cell you have one group that is radio button right ? and you want to allow only single selection to single cell

Comment: i think you need to maintain other button state (selected, deselected)also in radioButtonsClicked event.

Comment: @rohit Sidpara can u suggest an example how to do this

Comment: define the uniq tag for each button of group and access it by the tag and define it state (selected or not)

Answer (score 0):

You can set other button's selection status as following

```html
-(IBAction) radioButtonsClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
    
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    
    for (UIView *vw in sender.superview.subviews)
    {
        if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && vw != sender)
        {
            UIButton *otherBtn = (UIButton*)vw;
            otherBtn.selected = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

for setting button Image - on/off, write that code at the time of creating button in cellforrow..

```html
[_btTemp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_btTemp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Ok but by using this code we can only select a single button for a row right. but what i need is we can select only a single button for a **Column Group** and row has more than one column group

Comment: what do you mean by Column group? Can you please share screenshot ?