# Issue using Tags to retrieve data in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

When a user presses a button within a tableView cell I need to get that cell's data from the array the tableView was populated with. After using that data for something that cell is then removed from the tableView.

I'm using Tags to know the index of the cell who's button was pressed. However, once a cell in the middle of the tableView is removed along with its data from the array, the cells further down in the tableView now have buttons with tags that are out of the array's bound. For example:

```
array.length = 3
```

- Cell 0 (Button Tag: 0)
- Cell 1 (Button Tag: 1)
- Cell 2 (Button Tag: 2)

User then presses button inside Cell 1, which is then removed from the array and the table:

- Cell 0 (Button Tag: 0)
- Cell 2 (Button Tag: 2)

The problem now is that if the user presses Cell 2, when I try get that cell's data from the array using the Tag the app will crash since I'm accessing an out of bounds index. Therefore I'm starting to think that using tags isn't a good option and I'm wondering what's a better altenative. Here is my code:

```
var invitesArray = [userInfo]()

func declineInvite(sender: UIButton!) {
    let info = invitesArray[sender.tag]
    // I use info to process data 

    // Remove cell's data from array and remove cell from table
    inviteTable.beginUpdates()
    inviteTable.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    invitesArray.remove(at: sender.tag)
    inviteTable.endUpdates()
}

// Populating the tableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = inviteTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inviteCell", for: indexPath) as! joinCell
    cell.declineButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.declineButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.declineInvite), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)       
    return cell
}
```

Can anybody help correct my naive ways please?

Comment: Using tags based on row number only works if rows can't be inserted, removed, or moved.

Comment: Yes I understand that, hence this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift: how to get the indexpath.row when a button in a cell is tapped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped)

Comment: The only valid answer in that duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/a/35546504/1226963 but it's in Swift 2.

Comment: @rmaddy but the question is still technically a dupe

Comment: Actually http://stackoverflow.com/a/35249871/1226963 is also valid.

Comment: @JAL Technically but I hate closing a question as a dupe to a question where its top answers are actually wrong.

Comment: Perhaps not a valid dup, but I do believe it will get the OP to look at his problem in that light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use tags for this.  UITableView has a function [indexPathForCell](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614881-indexpathforcell) that will give you the indexPath.  Since your model should be in synch with your tableView when you add or remove items, you should use this indexPath to index into the array.  Tags are rarely necessary and usually bad practice.