# which cell button has pressed in tableView in swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uibutton, cell

I have read similar questions like this but these codes didn't worked for me so please help :
I have a table view with some buttons in each cells - This table view is factor for user and I added button to that tableview -  when user has paid money the button is hidden in that factor in that cell and in another cell for another factor when user didn't paid the pay money is not hidden - 
this is what I did 
I want to detect which cells button has pressed ?!
I know that in table view we can detect which cell has pressed But this is different because the user just press the Button in that cell Not press all of the Cell

As my codes are too long I Just Put the table view Codes here

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "factorCell", for: indexPath) as! FactorCell

    cell.factorTitle.text = factorTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.factorCode.text = factorCodes[indexPath.row]
    cell.factorDate.text = factorDate[indexPath.row]
    cell.factorHour.text = factorHour[indexPath.row]
    cell.factorPrice.text = factorPrice[indexPath.row]
    cell.factorCondition.text = factorConditions[indexPath.row]
    cell.factorBill.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.factorBill.addTarget(self,action:#selector(factorViewController.Bill), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    cell.factorDetail.tag = indexPath.row    

    cell.factorDetail.addTarget(self,action:#selector(factorViewController.FactorDetail), for: .touchUpInside)


    if   factorConditions[indexPath.row] == "پرداخت شده"  {


        cell.factorBill.isHidden = true


    } else {

        cell.factorCondition.textColor = UIColor.red

        cell.factorBill.isHidden = false

    }


    return cell

}
```

and this is the function that I want to:
when User Click to pay his Factor and press the button - Move to another view Controller and in that view controller the user could see these data here in that View Controller --

**Thanks a lot If you didn't understand What I want to do tell me and i will Explain More **

Comment: Can you update your Question with method #selector(factorViewController.Bill and #selector(factorViewController.FactorDetail

Comment: I Edited The Question

Comment: just give your button a tag. In the IBAction check for sender.tag

Comment: I added My Button As outlet And I know that I don't need to use IBAction can You help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Here is update

just leave it, i explained it more simple,
create a button action in your cell class,then
Writre the code:-

> //Cell class

protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func didTapCell(index: IndexPath)
}
  var delegateCell:CellDelegate?
  var indexPath:IndexPath?
 @IBAction func buttonCellClick(_ sender: Any) {
        delegateCell?.didTapCell(index: indexPath!)
    }

> //In ViewController

 cell.delegateCell = self
 cell.indexPath = indexPath

 func didTapCell(index: IndexPath) {
        print("PRESS BUTTON >> \(index.row)")
    }
```

Comment: please write the method or explain more

Comment: where should I write the method in view Controller ? because I can't use that in ViewDidLoad or cell for row at index path or In the Button IBAction ! another question : my codes are for IBOutlet can you help me to use that method without using @IBAction

Comment: If you don't use IBAction,then its ok, just use `factorBill.addTarget(self,action:#selector(factorViewController.Bill), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)`
in `cell` class

Comment: Ok Thanks Its Solved And there is one thing to complete this : in destination view controller I used     let titletext = factorViewController().factorTitle
to bring selected row in destination view controller but it doesn't work

Comment: Brother, in `didTapCell(index:IndexPath)` delegate function you only get indexpath, you have to use this indexpath to get the value from array(i.e 
`let value = array(indexpath.row)`)

Answer (score 8):

Create IBAction for you button in the custom cell class then declare a block that will be called on button click.

```
var ButtonHandler:(()-> Void)!

    @IBAction func ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
            self.ButtonHandler()
        }
```

Then in your tableview class inside the cell for row method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = playlistTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.ButtonHandler = {()-> Void in
            // your code 
        }
        return cell
}
```

Comment: my Button is IBOutlet Can I use some thing different without IBAction? or Not ?

Comment: you have to create an IBAction inside your cell that way you can diffrentiate cell click and button click

Answer (score 2):

You are setting factor button's tag in your `cellForRowAt` so you can easily get indexpath from your `factorViewController.Bill`, and from that indexpath you can get your whole cell and you can do whatever you need.

You can get cell like,

```
 let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

you can refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped) to know how to get indexpath from button click!

Comment: So Where Should I add this?

Comment: Please Explain More Because when I put this code to my codes I Cant run the app because of Error

Answer (score 1):

When you press `factorBill`button then your Bill method will call.So you can easily differentiate the button inside your Bill method by `sender.tag`.You already set the tag in `cellForRowAt`.