# How to present a ViewController after pressing a button inside of a CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, presentviewcontroller

Hey i'm new to programming and my problem is, i have a `UICollectionViewController` with 4 cells that are horizontal scrollable. Inside of the 4th cell i have a `UIButton`(`optionsButton`) on top of a `UIView` (`ProfileContainerView`).

The `UIViewController` I want to present is called `ProfileEditViewController` and is set up in `Main.storyboard`.

How can i present a `UIViewController` after pressing this button?

ProfileCell:

```
class ProfileCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let profileContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()

    lazy var optionsButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Settings"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptionsButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    @objc func handleOptionsButton() {
        print("Button pressed")
    }
}
```

HomeViewController:

```
class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    let profileCelId = "profileCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSwipeView()
    }


    func setupSwipeView() {
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cell)
        collectionView?.register(ProfileCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: profileCelId)        
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {        
        if indexPath.item == 3 {
            return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: profileCelId, for: indexPath)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766963/swift-action-button-inside-a-collectionviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can present your `ProfileEditViewController`, which is styled in your `Main.storyboard` the following way:

1) Give your `ProfileEditViewController` a `StoryBoard ID`. E.g. "ProfileEditViewController" -  Some question regarding this is here: [What is a StoryBoard ID and how can i use this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this)

2) Register the `UIViewController` for the action on the `UIButton` or offer an appropriate callback functionality.
As your `HomeViewController` is also your Collection View's datasource, you can easily extend your DataSource method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`
```

Implementation could look like:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {        
    if indexPath.item == 3 {
        let profileCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: profileCelId, for: indexPath)
        if let _cell = cell as? ProfileCell,
           let button = _cell.optionsButton as? UIButton {
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptionsButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        }
        return profileCell;
    }
    return cell
}
```

Make sure that your buttons Action is now also being implemented by your `HomeViewController`

```
@objc func handleOptionsButton() {
    print("Button pressed")
}
```

3) Now in `HomeViewController.handleOptionsButton` you need to provide a functionality to support the transition to that specific Controller with the desired StoryboardID:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:Bundle.main)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileEditViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried but it shows that Value of type 'ProfileCell' has no member 'present'

Comment: present is a function implemented by `UIViewControllers` see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present. You can register your UIViewController for the action of the Uibutton for example. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Ok I'll try this and let you know if it worked. Thanks for your time

Comment: after if let button = profileCell.optionsButton as? UIButton {
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptionsButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            }

Comment: it says Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'optionsButton'

Comment: is there something wrong with the setup? func setupOptionsButton() {
        profileContainerView.addSubview(optionsButton)
    }

Comment: Well, the compiler was not aware of the cell being of type "ProfileCell" - I have updated the method

Comment: So i tried that and when i click the button, it only shows the print statement inside of ProfileCell and not the one in the HomeViewController. I commented ProfileCell.handleOptionsButton out and nothing is printed into the console.

Comment: As you Button appears to be declared as lazy, do you even get to the part where your button gets the target added:             button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptionsButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
 - Set a breakpoint and investigate the issue.

Comment: Oh yes i got it and i learned a lot thanks. I added a comment if you wanna see what i did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegates to implement this.

Below is the code to implement this

```
 protocol ProfileCollectionViewCellDelegate {
 func buttonPressedAtIndexPath(inCell: ProfileCell)
 }

class ProfileCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var delegate : ProfileCollectionViewCellDelegate?
let profileContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()

lazy var optionsButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Settings"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptionsButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()

@objc func handleOptionsButton() {
    if self.delegate != nil {
        self.delegate?.buttonPressedAtIndexPath(self)
    }
}
}
```

For your HomeViewController

```
 class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, ProfileCollectionViewCellDelegate  {


let profileCelId = "profileCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupSwipeView()
}


func setupSwipeView() {
    collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cell)
    collectionView?.register(ProfileCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: profileCelId)        
}


  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {        

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: profileCelId, for: indexPath)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
 }

fun buttonPressedAtIndexPath(inCell: ProfileCell) {
       let indexOfCell = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        if indexOfCell.row == 3 {
            //Do your work here
        }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll try that

Comment: Frank did you try?

Comment: Sorry i haven't noticed that you wrote me

Comment: Yes, i tried. But unfortunately it didn't work for me. But thanks for your answer and time anyways!

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: I don't know. But "let proCell = ProfileCell" just had to be outside of cell for item at index path. I posted the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

let proCell = ProfileCell()

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cell, for: indexPath)
    if indexPath.item == 3 {
        let profileCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: profileCelId, for: indexPath)
        let button = proCell.optionsButton
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptionsButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return profileCell;
    }
    return cell
}
```