# How do I reference a UITableViewCell in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

The table view and cells have been created and populated with a label and slider.I have an IBAction on the slider when the value is changed.

How do I get that value back into the label in the cell?

I have an IBOutlet linked in the table view.

```
@IBAction func slideChange(_ sender: UISlider) {

    let currentValue = sender.value    // gets slider's value
    let row = sender.tag               // gets slider's row in table

    myTableView.cell.myLabel.text = sender.value  // Here i need to show updated value


    print("Slider in row \(row) has a value of \(currentValue)")  // works
}
```

Comment: you need to reload either tableview or specific cell and than in the cellforRowAtIndexpath method, try to set that value to that cell.

Comment: Handle the slider in your cell and use a delegate or a closure see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/38941510#38941510

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Get a reference to the table view cell

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0))
```

Update its label

```
cell?.myLabel.text = sender.value
```

Note: This method returns nil when cell is not visible. In your case this won't be an issue.

Comment: Brilliant. And so simple when you know how. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I think what you are missing is to update your data model, so that _cellForItem_ method configures the cell with the updated value when scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func slideChange(_ sender: UISlider){
     let cell: UITableViewCell? = (sender.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell)  // track cell using your view hierarchy and this your cell
     cell.myLabel.text = sender.value
}
```

**OR**

```
  let rootViewPoint: CGPoint? = sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to: tblView)
   var indexPath: IndexPath? = tblView?.indexPathForRow(at: rootViewPoint!)
   let cell: UITableViewCell? = tblView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)
```

Comment: @Sean did you try this answer ?

Comment: Yeah. I was wrong about the superview count. I needed to change the UITableViewCell type to PersonTableCell (as I have my class) and remove the optional on it. And I needed to force unwrap the whole cell. Works

Comment: Sometimes answer is for only suggestion . you have to make some changes on answer for get desired output.

Comment: then why down voting .. you can ask alternate for view count .

Comment: I didn't downvote. I can't even vote with my reputation score yet. :( I upvoted!

Comment: Then why did you accept answer. @KKRocks already answered that? why did you say brilliant in that answer? Reviewer team pls have a look.

Comment: @Sean what is the difference in my answer and accepted answer ?

Comment: why down voting ?

Comment: 1) I didn't down vote any answer. 
2) The accepted was the one I ended up using. Both work. I personally find the accepted one slightly more elegant than traversing the object tree.