# Swift 4 - How to activate segue programmatically from button nested in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, swift4, xcode9

I am trying to activate a segue between a UICollectionView, subview of a UIViewController, and a separate ViewController (called RegisterController). The CollectionView is all set up programmatically, and there is a button on the last cell. However, I can't do the typical `performSegue(_:withIdentfier)` because the button is in the CollectionView. So, I have set up a method in the ViewController holding the CollectionView to `performSegue(_:withIdentifier)`. I set up an instance in the CollectionViewController to call the method:

```
lazy var registerButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.setTitle("Don't have an account?", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(lighterOrange, for: .normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerScreenAppear), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()

@objc func registerScreenAppear(){
    let vc: ViewController = ViewController()
    _ = vc.toRegister()
}
```

The method in the ViewController is

```
func toRegister(){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRegister", sender: self)
}
```

I am getting the call stack: 
    `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver      (<audible.ViewController: 0x7fe780724770>) has no segue with identifier 'toRegister''`

I know I'm probably doing something completely wrong, but I've searched and searched and can't find a solution. Any help is appreciated, thanks

(Yes, I have configured the segue and gave it an identifier in the storyboard, but the reason I have to do this through code is because the CollectionView and the button are created programmatically, so I can't use the Interface Builder)

Comment: In Storyboard, press and hold key control, and drag a line from ViewController to RegisterController to create a segue named "toRegister".

Comment: @YunCHEN I have already done that

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your view controller, not referring to the existing instance.  This new instance isn't linked to the storyboard since you have used a simple initialiser to create it.  You need to use delegation or a closure.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/38941510#38941510 for some ideas on how to get an event from a cell back to a view controller

Answer (score 1):

call `performSegu`e in registerScreenAppear method or call `self.toRegister()` like

```
@objc func registerScreenAppear(){
    self.toRegister()
}
```

OR

```
 @objc func registerScreenAppear(){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRegister", sender: self)
 }
```

Note: use later one as it will remove the extra function call i.e. toRegister().

Comment: Because the registerScreenAppear method is in a UICollectionViewCell class, perfromSegue(_:withIdentifier) will give an 'Unresolved use of identifier' error.

Comment: Okay got your problem, you can move the addTarget line: "    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerScreenAppear), for: .touchUpInside)
" to view controller and add it in cellForItem method while configuring cell. and also move the respective target method to view controller.