# What exactly is the IndexPath of a UICollection

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I'm having 2 problems with UICollectionViews, and I somehow believe it's related to the IndexPath in both cases, however I don't really know when is the Indexpath called or what exactly it does and when it gets updated or changed.
Anyways, here are my issues:
1. Somehow the Indexpath is 0 multiple times?[Youtube VIDEO showing behavior](https://youtu.be/3da2Q9dMv0c)

for this particular behavior here is the code:

```
extension PointAllocVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (playerArray?.count)!
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as! PointAllocCell
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row
        cell.nameLabel.text = playerArray![indexPath.row].alias
        cell.scoreLabel.text = String(currentScore[indexPath.row])
        cell.minusBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        cell.plusBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        cell.ptsRemaining = pointsToAllocate
        cell.ptsUsed = abs(pointsUsedInCells[indexPath.row])
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.isSelf = true
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        } else {
            cell.isSelf = false
        }
        cell.updatedButtons()
        return cell
    }
```

As you can see ONLY AT INDEXPATH.ROW == 0 should the cell have a border (because thats' the current user). However when I click the buttons (see button logic below) suddenly they're all index path == 0?

```
class PointAllocCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var isSelf: Bool = false
    var cellIndex: Int?
    var ptsRemaining: Int = 0
    var ptsUsed: Int = 0
    var cellDelegate: PointsAllocDelegate?

    @IBAction func plusTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if cellDelegate != nil {
            cellDelegate!.plusTapReported(fromCell: cellIndex!)
        }
        updatedButtons()
    }

    @IBAction func minusTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if cellDelegate != nil {
            cellDelegate!.minusTapReported(fromCell: cellIndex!)
        }
        updatedButtons()
    }

    func updatedButtons() {
        switch (ptsRemaining, ptsUsed) {
        case (0,0):
            plusBtn.isEnabled = false
            minusBtn.isEnabled = false
        case (0,_):
            if isSelf{
                plusBtn.isEnabled = false
                minusBtn.isEnabled = true
            } else {
                plusBtn.isEnabled = true
                minusBtn.isEnabled = false
            }
        case (_,0):
            if isSelf{
                plusBtn.isEnabled = true
                minusBtn.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                plusBtn.isEnabled = false
                minusBtn.isEnabled = true
            }
        default:
            plusBtn.isEnabled = true
            minusBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
        pointLabel.text = String(ptsUsed)
    }
}
```

AND finally the delegate:

```
extension PointAllocVC: PointsAllocDelegate {
    func plusTapReported(fromCell: Int) {
        if fromCell == 0 {
            //this is self
            pointsToAllocate -= 1
            pointsUsedInCells[fromCell] += 1
        } else {
            pointsToAllocate += 1
            pointsUsedInCells[fromCell] += 1
        }
        reloadCollection()
        reloadLabels()
    }

    func minusTapReported(fromCell: Int) {
        if fromCell == 0 {
            //this is self
            pointsToAllocate += 1
            pointsUsedInCells[fromCell] -= 1
        } else {
            pointsToAllocate -= 1
            pointsUsedInCells[fromCell] -= 1
        }
        reloadCollection()
        reloadLabels()
    }
}
```

Now. The SECOND ISSUE, I'm getting it when I do the following

```
playerArray.remove(at: gKPlayerArray.index(of: playerDed)!)
```

This line of code doesn't do anything, however AFTER that when I call the "reloadData" I get that the IndexPath.row is out of range (for some reason it still thinks that the playerArray is a size X+1 even though I removed an item before calling it.

Comment: Regarding your 1st issue, you must explicitly set your border in your `else` body as well since cells are reused.

Answer (score 1):

A cell never needs to know its own indexPath. That's a a really bad design.

Refactor your code so you do not pass a row or indexPath to a cell.

Change your cell delegate protocol to pass the actual cell, not an `Int`.

The class that actually implements the delegate methods will now be told which cell the delegate method is being called on behalf of and if needed, that class can determine the indexPath of the cell.

You also need to update your `cellForItemAt`.

This code is an issue:

```
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.isSelf = true
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    } else {
        cell.isSelf = false
    }
```

Whenever you set a property, you must always reset it for the other condition.

```
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.isSelf = true
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    } else {
        cell.isSelf = false
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
```

You don't need to reset the color for a 0 width border.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? how would I sent the index of the cell back to the delegate so it updates the array of scores? like would my function be `cellDelegate!.minusTapReported(fromCell: self)` but what would that return? what type of data is "self" ?

Comment: You don't send the index to the delegate. That was my whole point. The delegate should be given the cell, not the index. Then the delegate can ask the collection view what the indexPath is for the cell.

Comment: Ok so I send "self", and then how do I convert that to indexPath? do you have any examples that you could point me to? thank you by the way!

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UICollectionView`. There's an obvious method for getting an indexPath for a cell.

Comment: `func indexPath(for: UICollectionViewCell)`
Returns the index path of the specified cell. However. How do I pass that to the delegate? If I return "self" I get a bunch of errors and I can't tell the delegate method something like `func minusTapReported(fromCell: UICollectionViewCell)` because that throws errors as well ** EDIT ** FOUND THE ISSUE. missing Import UIKit in the delegate swift file

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 0):

One thing has not been mentioned in answer by @rmaddy - since you are using `UICollectionView`, you shouldn’t use the `row` property of `IndexPath`, but rather the `item` property. Given the nature of the collection view and its flexibility in layouting cells, the system has no way of discerning „rows”. The `row` property should be used when working with `UITableView`.

> **var row: Int**
>   An index number identifying a row in a section of a table view.
>   **var item: Int**
>   An index number identifying an item in a section of a collection view.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexpath