# Compiler is complaining that cell is nil when I try to get indexpath.row when button is tapped on cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

Here is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CellAvailableJobs = self.tblJobs.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellAvailableJobs") as! CellAvailableJobs
    let jobsNearByObj:JobsNearBy = self.jobsArray![indexPath.row]
    cell.loadCell(jobsNearByObj: jobsNearByObj)
    cell.btnHeart.addTarget(self, action: #selector(JobsVC.btnBookmarkAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.btnHeart.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}

@IBAction func btnBookmarkAction(_ sender: AnyObject){
    let button = sender as? UIButton
    print("tag: \(String(describing: button?.tag))")
    let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = tblJobs.indexPath(for: cell!)
    print("bookmarkedJobId: \(String(describing: indexPath.row))")
}
```

I'm fetching data from web and populating them on tableview, everything is working well. I want to print indexpath.row when the button on cell is tapped. On above method the compiler is complaining that the cell is nil. This line: let indexPath = tblJobs.indexPath(for: cell!).

**What is the problem with this code. How the cell is nil in this code. Can anyone help me with this issue?**

Comment: The _compiler_ knows nothing of the cell being `nil`. The problem occurs at runtime.

Comment: @Matt ok thank you. there was another view on hierarchy. I forgot that. :) let cell = button?.superview?.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell ...this line works

Comment: Excellent. I suggest deleting the question.

Comment: @Sptibo Don't navigate the cell view hierarchy. It is fragile. Don't use tags. They are fragile. Engineer a proper solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/38941510#38941510

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when cell is currently not visible it's value is nil , you can't explicitly unwrap an optional value

```
let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
```

Try this

```
 if(cell != nil)
{
   let indexPath = tblJobs.indexPath(for: cell!)
}
```

beside type of cell is `CellAvailableJobs`  and you use `as? UITableViewCell`

Comment: @ Sh_Khan But it is crashing when i tap on cell button. That means cell is visible. Or not?

Comment: cell is nil. I've applied guard let statement also..it prevents the app from crash but I am unable to get indexpath.row

Comment: where do you add it ?? above the table ?

Answer (score 0):

Line `let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell` seems to fail to be the `UITableViewCell` instance, thus `cell` is `nil`.

As you figured out, this is what you wanted in fact:

```
let cell = button?.superview?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
```

Comment: @Sptibo show your hierarchy how you add button to the cell