# How to get the selected cell index path Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view in my VC. Inside the cell there are some lables and buttons. I passed the values in my labels, now i'm trying that when i hit a button that is also in that cell it should increment the value of the label. The value in that label is coming from previous VC. I have made a delegate for it when button is pressed, when button is pressed it should increment the value of label by the first price which is present in it. i'M TRYING to get that cell index path but not geeting it. My code is this,
In my cel class i have this protocol,

```
protocol cartDelegate {
func addTappedInCell(_ cell: CartTableViewCell)
func minusTappedInCell(_ cell: CartTableViewCell)
```

}

```
var delegate : cartDelegate?
@IBAction func addBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    delegate?.addTappedInCell(self)
}

@IBAction func minusBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

   delegate?.minusTappedInCell(self)
}
```

and in my view controller i'm trying this,

```
extension CartViewController : cartDelegate{

func addTappedInCell(_ cell: CartTableViewCell) {


    guard let indexPath = cartTableView?.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    print(indexPath)

    total += 1
    cell.totalLbl.text = String(total)
    print(cell.priceLbl.text!)
    count = "5"

    let tPrice = cell.priceLbl.text! + count
    print(tPrice)
    cell.priceLbl.text = String(tPrice)
    subTotalLbl.text = cell.priceLbl.text

}

func minusTappedInCell(_ cell: CartTableViewCell) {
    total -= 1
    cell.totalLbl.text = String(total)
    price = Int(cell.priceLbl.text!)! - Int(count)!
    cell.priceLbl.text = String(price)
    subTotalLbl.text = cell.priceLbl.text
}
```

I'm not getting the indexPath of that cell which button is pressed. 
This is how my screen looks,
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42043277/1630618).

Comment: what do you want to do with index as you have cell reference and updating value for the cell correctly?

Comment: i'm trying to update the value of price when + button hits and its should only increment that cell price which button is hit. @HarshalBhavsar

Comment: And the above code is not working?

Comment: no it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the custom cell class declare a var

```
   var cellIndex:NSIndexPath?
```

and in cellForRow set it

```
   cell.cellIndex = indexPath
```

and then access it anywhere

OR
 directly use

```
 var index = tableView.indexPath(for:cell)
```

Comment: how can i increment the price of that label of which button is hit? @Sh_Khan

Comment: with cellIndex here , you can get the the value assigned to the label from the model array , increment it and set it to the label but also override it to the old one in the array as user may scroll and last increment lost

Comment: how to ovveride that? @Sh_Khan

Comment: write the new value (the incremented one ) to the same index of the array that you read the old from

Comment: Bro i have printed the print(cell.cellIndex), and it shows this in console Optional(<NSIndexPath: 0x1631ca660> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}) . and when added the value it shows me this result, 7.07.0
. @Sh_Khan

Comment: assign it to the label

Comment: it should come 14 bcz i have added 7.0 + 7.0 but it is coming7.07.0 . @Sh_Khan

Comment: you add it as string or float ??? , re check  the addition

Comment: The are string. @Sh_Khan

Comment: convert them to float add them then convert result to string

Comment: let me try it, can u please confirm me that when i hit any cell + button it will increment only that cell values? @Sh_Khan

Comment: yes, if you only changed the index of the array corresponding to that cell only

Comment: how can i change that index? @Sh_Khan

Comment: How can i changed that index for the array?

Comment: re-assign the new calculated value to that index you read the value from like this arr[index] = newValue

Comment: Bro the problem is coming that i'm not getting the index path when i press the button. @Sh_Khan

Comment: cellIndex is the indexPath use it to index the array

Comment: this is my array  of  in cellForRow where i'm assigning the value  cell.priceLbl.text = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price! where should i give  cellIndex? @Sh_Khan

Comment: access it inside **addTappedInCell** as cell.cellIndex  and use it to index the array

Comment: i have used it is showing an error,  ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[cell.cellIndex].addPrice

Comment: you forget .row Use **ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[cell.cellIndex.row].addPrice**

Comment: showing me this error.Expression resolves to an unused l-value. @Sh_Khan