# tableview issue, indexPath is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a button and a label in a table view (I am using 8 rows )and for some reason when I click the first button I get indexPath nil error, but when I click the second button (2nd row) I get the first row label. When I click the 3rd row button, I get the second row label etc. Why are they misaligned. I want when I click the first row button to get the first row label etc. Please see the code below. Thank you !!

```
   @objc func btnAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    var position: CGPoint = sender.convert(.zero, to: self.table)

    print (position)
    let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForRow(at: position)
    print (indexPath?.row)
    let cell: UITableViewCell = table.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as
    UITableViewCell


      print (indexPath?.row)
    print (currentAnimalArray[(indexPath?.row)!].name)
    GlobalVariable.addedExercises.append(currentAnimalArray[(indexPath?.row)!].name)

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? TableCell else {return UITableViewCell() }

   // print(indexPath)

    cell.nameLbl.text=currentAnimalArray[indexPath.row].name
 // print("\(#function) --- section = \(indexPath.section), row = \(indexPath.row)")

   // print (currentAnimalArray[indexPath.row].name)

    cell.b.tag = indexPath.row

   // print (indexPath.row)
    cell.b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SecondVC.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    return cell



}
```

Comment: are you sure u r getting `position` right?

Comment: Frame math is rather the worst way to get the index path. Why don't you use the tag you assigned to the button? I recommend to move the button action into the (custom) cell and use a callback closure which is the most efficient solution.

Comment: @vadian thanks, do you have an example on how I can do that?

Comment: @Bubu **Try this One** https://stackoverflow.com/q/28659845/10150796

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani thanks that link you gave fixed my issue of position

Comment: @Bubu Welcome Dear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame math is a worst-case scenario if you have no choice. Here you have a lot of choices.

For example why don't you use the `tag` you assigned to the button?

```
@objc func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    GlobalVariable.addedExercises.append(currentAnimalArray[sender.tag].name)
}
```

---

A *swiftier* and more efficient solution is a callback closure:

In `TableCell` add the button action and a `callback` property. The outlet is not needed. Disconnect the outlet and connect the button to the action in Interface Builder. When the button is tapped the callback is called.

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    // @IBOutlet var b : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var nameLbl : UILabel!

    var callback : (()->())?

    @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?()
    }
}
```

Remove the button action in the controller.

In `cellForRow` assign a closure to the `callback` property

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // no guard, the code must not crash. If it does you made a design mistake
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableCell

    let animal = currentAnimalArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLbl.text = animal.name

    cell.callback = {
         GlobalVariable.addedExercises.append(animal.name)
    }

    return cell
}
```

You see the index path is actually not needed at all. The `animal` object is captured in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

You already pass `indexPath.row` with button tag. Use the tag as index simply

```
@objc func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    GlobalVariable.addedExercises.append(currentAnimalArray[sender.tag].name)
}
```

Comment: This does not compile

Comment: Yes, but it's much easier to change the type of the `sender` in the signature

Comment: Yes got it. Changed.