# After delete rows table view has old indexes Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have table view that delete some rows with following:

```
func deleteRows(_ indecies: [Int]) {
    guard !indecies.isEmpty else { return }
    let indexPathesToDelete: [IndexPath] = indecies.map{ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}
    let previousIndex = IndexPath(row: indecies.first! - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathesToDelete, with: .none)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [previousIndex], with: .none)
  }
```

In `cellForRow` i have cell that have "tap" closure like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard indexPath.row < presenter.fields.count else { return EmptyCell() }
    let field = presenter.fields[indexPath.row]
    switch field.cellType {
    case .simple:
      guard let model = field as? SimpleTextItem else { return EmptyCell() }
      let cell = SimpleTextCell()
      cell.setup(label: LabelSL.regularSolidGray(), text: model.text, color: Theme.Color.bleakGray)
      return cell
    case .organization:
      guard let model = field as? OrganizationFilterItem else { return EmptyCell() }
      let cell = OrganizationFilterCell()
      cell.setup(titleText: model.title,
                 holdingNumberText: model.holdingNumberText,
                 isChosed: model.isChosed,
                 isHolding: model.isHolding,
                 isChild: model.isChild,
                 bottomLineVisible: model.shouldDrawBottomLine)

      cell.toggleControlTapped = {[weak self] in
        self?.presenter.tappedItem(indexPath.row)
      }
      return cell
    }
  }
```

When

```
cell.toggleControlTapped = {[weak self] in
            self?.presenter.tappedItem(indexPath.row)
          }
```

Tapped after rows deletion, index is pass is wrong (it's old). For example, i have 10 rows, i delete 2-3-4-5 row, and then i tap on 2 row (it was 6 before deletion). That method pass "6" instead of "2".

Problem actually was solved by adding `tableView.reloadData(`) in `deleteRows` function, but, as you may assume smoothly animation gone and it look rough and not nice. Why is table still pass old index and how to fix it?

Comment: DId you to try to add tableView.reloadData() ? on the last line of the function "deleteRows(_ indecies: [Int])" ?

Comment: The closure captures the index path when the cell is created, and that becomes invalid as soon as rows are inserted or deleted. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/28659845/1187415 for better methods to get the current index path of a cell.

Answer (score 1):

A quite easy solution is to pass the cell in the closure to be able to get the **actual** index path

Delare it

```
var toggleControlTapped : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
```

Call it

```
toggleControlTapped?(self)
```

Handle it

```
cell.toggleControlTapped = {[weak self] cell in
    guard let actualIndexPath = self?.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    self?.presenter.tappedItem(actualIndexPath.row)
}
```

Side note: Reuse cells. Creating cells with the default initializer is pretty bad practice.

Comment: thanks for answer, what you mean with - Side note: Reuse cells. Creating cells with the default initializer is pretty bad practice. Can you provide example with "good" practice?

Comment: The *good* practice is the standard practice: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleTextCell`. `TextCell` is the identifier specified in Interface Builder.

Comment: @vadian, nice answer, it is interesting that If I use the default `indexPath` in func `cellForRowAt` & `reloadData()` instead of retrieving the indexPath with `tableView.indexPath(for: cell)`, this issue is not exist. But some of tableView of my app are using `deleteRows()`, then it will fail. It seems to me that tableView don't reload indexPath when you do `deleteRows`, so the next time delete will delete the previous indexPath stuff. Then we should fetch it manually.

Comment: @ChuckZHB When cells are removed with  `deleteRows(at:with:` then `cellForRowAt` is not called therefore the index path is not being updated. That's the reason to get the **actual** index path in the closure.

Answer (score -2):

Be sure to update your data too, indexes are appearing from numberofrows function of table view

Comment: Answer should be more explanatory!