# Save button in table

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of data that is taken from the site and output to the table, I want to add a button that will store a certain row from the table in the database how can I implement it?

```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)
   cell.textLabel?.text = news[indexPath.row].tittle

   let tipDouble = NumberFormatter().number(from: news[indexPath.row].time!)!.doubleValue
   let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: tipDouble)

   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+2") //Set timezone that you want
   dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd HH:mm" //Specify your format that you want

   let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = strDate

   return cell
```

Comment: Where do you want the button, in each cell?

Comment: Unrelated, I would move the `NumberFormatter` and `DataFormatter` code outside `cellForRowAt` into your datamodel code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/38941510#38941510

Comment: @koen 
I want to put a button in each line and when you click on the button for example in the second line the second line is saved

Answer (score 1):

**Use Tag.**
set a tag to button. Give Tag value as index path.row value. Then on Button click you can access the corresponding data(if array) at index.

Ex:

```
var arrData = ["5","6","7","8"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   cell.button.tag = IndexPath.row

}

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton){

   let data = arrData[sender.tag]

}
```

Comment: Please attach example code so the op can understand the solution.

Comment: He explained the solution. Writing code is the easy part.

Comment: Tags is not a good idea for table cells, after user adds or removes data you will get the wrong button.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy and simple workaround is to set the button tag property as the row number and in the button action get the button tag to do your stuff i.e.

In your tableView(:cellForRowAt:indexPath) add the button tag as row number:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewClass
cell.[buttonName].tag = indexPath.row (In case you are just using the single section)
```

And then in your button action in viewController use the tag of button to track the row i.e.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let row = sender.tag
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with this. The row number of a cell can change. For example, if you remove a row before it, or insert a new road. You should store something that lets you identify the cell within your data source, independent of changes.

Comment: Yes, using `tag` isn't the best approach - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/38941510 for some more sophisticated approaches

Comment: Yes, it is not the best approach but for simple cases you use that way as it is really simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Exactly If going through delete and insert. But there is a solution for this.

```
var arrData: dataTag = [dataTag]()

class dataTag {
    var name:String?
    .......

    var tag: Int? =  Date().IntegerValue. Here "anyUniqueEntry value". 
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
cell.button.tag = IndexPath.row
..

}
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton){

let data = arrData[sender.tag]

...

}
```