# How can I get the IndexPath of a textField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am using a sectioned tableView in my app, each row of the tableView contains a textField, when `textFieldDidBeginEditing` I need to know the indexPath of that textField. Using the tag can only get the section or row, and creating an extension of `UITextField` doesn't allow you to add variables. How can I get this done?

Comment: If there are UITextFields within your UITableView cells then I believe your didSelect(:IndexPath) stub should be firing when the UITextField becomes first responder. Explore that first. If that doesn’t work, try to override the UITextField class with a Closure to execute on becoming first responder.

Comment: You can subclass UITextField and add a indexPath property to it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yq641m7g5v6a7g/TableView%20with%20TextFields.zip?dl=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-element-is-activated

Answer (score 4):

I like to walk from the text field to the cell and ask the table view for its index path.

```
extension UIResponder {
    func next<T:UIResponder>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        let r = self.next
        if let r = r as? T ?? r?.next(ofType: T.self) {
            return r
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let cell = textField.next(ofType: MyCell.self) {
        if let ip = self.tableView.indexPath(for:cell) {
           // whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `next` equivalent to `superView`? I never used that before.

Comment: @Tj3n it is the responder chain, it embraces the view hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

There are way to do it but it's bad design anyway, suggest you to put the textfield delegate inside the cell class.

You can try to get the exact cell/contentView with `textField.superview`, convert it to `MyTableViewCell`, then use `tableView.indexPath(for: cell)` to get index.

No need for tags to do it.

Example:

```
var view: UIView = textField
while !view.isKind(of: UITableViewCell.self), let superView = view.superview {
    view = superView
}
if let view = view as? MyTableViewCell {
   //Do sth
}
```

Comment: This won’t compile as it stands, because `view` is implicitly typed as UITextField. You must explicitly type it as UIView.

Answer (score 1):

in `cellForRow`

```
var section = indexPath.section + 1
var row = indexPath.row + 1
index = Int("\(section)0\(row)")!
```

setting the textFields' tags to `index`

in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
let indexString = "\(textField.tag)"
let parts = indexString.components(separatedBy: "0")
let row = Int(parts[1])! - 1
let section = Int(parts[0])! - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get indexPath of cell that contain textfield

```
func getIndexPathFromView(_ sender : UIView) -> IndexPath? {
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tblView)
    let indexPath = self.tblView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    return indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the `UITextField` delegate. In my own way, to find the index path of the cell with the text field that is currently being edited. I created an `IBAction` outlet, `editingTextField`, that its event is "Editing did begin". So, whenever a user clicks on the text field, this function is invoked. Also, I created an array `var cellArray = [UITableViewCell]()` that is appended each cell in `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier") as! CellIdentifier
        //whatever

        cellArray.append(cell)
        return cell
    }
```

You iterate through this array in your `IBAction` outlet and for each cell, you check if its text field is currently being edited with `textField.isEditing`. If the text field is in fact being edited, you can get the index path of the current cell by using `tableView.indexPath(for: myCell)` where `myCell` is the current cell instance.

See below:

```
    @IBAction func numberChange(_ sender: Any) {
        for cell in cellArray {
            let myCell = cell as! SelectExerciseNumTableViewCell
            if(myCell.numExercisesField.isEditing) {
                //indexPath is declared outside of this scope
                indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: myCell)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also use this to update text in the current cell, which is what I used it for.