# Tap on button in table view and song will play in each of rows using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have a list of songs which should be played in each of row in table view by tapping on the button. I've made a button in custom cell and a protocol which used to display the tap in our view controller. For ex. when we tap on second button in cell, it should play second song, when we tap on third button, its play third song.

My ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class BeatPackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var beatTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var coverImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var looppackNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var producerNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButtonLabel: UIButton!

    let data = DataLoader().beatData
    var songs: [String] = []
    
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    func getSongs() -> [String] {
        var names: [String] = []
        let path = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("songs")
        do {
            let songs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: path!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles)
            
            for song in songs {
                let strArray = song.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "/")
                var songName = strArray[strArray.count - 1].replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")
                songName = songName.replacingOccurrences(of: ".wav", with: "")
                names.append(songName)
            }
        } catch {}
        
        return names
    }
    
    func playSong(index: Int) {
        do {
            let songPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[index], ofType: ".wav", inDirectory: "songs")
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: songPath!))
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {}
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        beatTableView.delegate = self
        beatTableView.dataSource = self
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = SettingsService.sharedService.backgroundColor
        coverImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        coverImage.layer.shadowRadius = 7
        coverImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        coverImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        coverImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        coverImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
}



extension BeatPackViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = beatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstLoopCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomLoopsCell
        cell.loopNameLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].loop_name
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.playButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomLoopsCell.playButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        //        cell.instrumentLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].loops[indexPath.row].Instrument
        //        cell.producerLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].loops[indexPath.row].producer
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        didTapButton()
    }
    
}

extension BeatPackViewController: CustomLoopsDelegate {
    func didTapButton() {
    }
    
}
```

My CustomCell

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol CustomLoopsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didTapButton()
}

class CustomLoopsCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomLoopsDelegate?
    
    var songs: [String] = []
    
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var loopNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var producerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var instrumentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didTapButton()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: first of all remove `didTapButton` from `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: You can't add the button tap handler in `cellForRowAt` because cells are reused as you scroll and you will end up adding multiple tap handlers to the same button.  Use one of these techniques.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-an-element-is-activated/38941510#38941510

Comment: The problem is that I figured out how to make tappable button in our cell, but how I can do that when we tap on each button in each of raw and that it will play different sound from songs array?

Comment: What is a guy named 'data' and where does it come from?

Comment: @ElTomato its from file with json data

Comment: What kind of information does 'data' contain?

Comment: let loop_name: String
    let Instrument: String
    let loop_link: String
    let producer: String

Answer (score 1):

as [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) said don't use btn action in `cellForRowAt` you need to add `delegate`. check code i tried regarding yours. here you don't need `didSelect` method

**BeatPackViewController.Swift**

```
class BeatPackViewController: UIViewController, CustomLoopsDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : CustomLoopsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstLoopCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLoopsCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    
    func btnUseTap(cell: CustomLoopsCell) {
        let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
        //play song here
    }

}
```

**CustomLoopsCell.Swift**

```
protocol CustomLoopsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func btnUseTap(cell: CustomLoopsCell)
}

class CustomLoopsCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomLoopsDelegate?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnUse(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.btnUseTap(cell: self)
    }
    
}
```

**Update song play code**

```
let audioData = try! Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        do {
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.m4a.rawValue)
            self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            self.audioPlayer.play()
            if isVideoMute {
                self.audioPlayer.volume = 0
            }else {
                self.audioPlayer.volume = 1
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Comment: Fixed this now, but now how I can play song in each of the rows by clicking this button which I have?

Comment: can you see func `btnUseTap` there you find `index` which you select from table.  play song there from index.

Comment: I've used there this methods playSong(index: indexPath!.row) and I've got an error "Index out of range"

Comment: make sure `songs` array can't be nil and also check index you get is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, could you check if my method to play songs is correct, I've had a folder inside my project which named "Songs" and method in view controller

Comment: @mozeX check my code i used it this way. you need to change file hint there cause you used `.wav` file an i used `.mp4`

Comment: it looks good! But where you get this "url"?

Comment: from device where i stored songs. as i seen you get from bundle so you directly get by name.

Comment: Need to change .wav in the each of songs in folder or how?

Comment: no need to change formate of song change in my last code this line  `self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.m4a.rawValue)`

Comment: func playSong(index: Int) {
        do {
            let songPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[index], ofType: ".wav", inDirectory: "songs")
            let audioData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: songPath!), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
                    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                    do {
                        self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)

Comment: I changed it to this and again index out of range

Comment: did you check array and index here `let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)`?

Comment: I have now like this func btnUseTap(cell: CustomLoopsCell) {
        let indexPath = self.beatTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        playSong(index: indexPath!.row)

Comment: Hey! I've fixed this, now everything works, thanks! Also, maybe you how I can make the same, but from local JSON file?