# How to handle Button Actions for Buttons within a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm working on a shopping app project where customers can browse through products and add them to their cart, but am having trouble figuring out how to handle button presses within the tableViewCell. They way I want it to work is that when the empty circle button is pressed, the image changes to a filled circle with a checkmark, and the product within that cell is added to the customers "cart". The "cart" consists of two arrays `products` and `quantities` held within my CustomerOrder object.

Here's what the tableView looks like:

[image: image of my UI]

Here's my code so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductToBuyCell") as! ProductToBuyCell
    
    //Configure the Selection Button
    cell.selectButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ItemSelected), for: .touchUpInside)
    let product = productsArray[indexPath.row]
    //configure cell
    cell.productImg.image = product.productPhoto
    cell.productImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    cell.productName.text = product.Name
    cell.price.text = "$\(product.price)"
    
    return cell
}
// func for when the selectButton is tapped
// tag is equal to indexPath.row
@objc func ItemSelected(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
    let product = productsArray[sender.tag]
    newOrder.products.append(product)
    newOrder.quantities.append(1)
}
```

So if someone could please explain how to properly handle events that are caused by elements within a UITableViewCell and how to get the buttons image to change, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? Also note what you've depicted here is not using `IBAction`; you are linking the action using `addTarget` in your code.

Comment: The problem is that the button image doesn't change when tapped. I know I'm not using an IBAction but I'll modify the question for more clarity

Comment: Because cells are reused you will add you action handler multiple times.  You also need to work out which cell was tapped, `tag` isn't a great solution since the default is 0 and it will break if rows are reordered.  You also need to reload the relevant row when the button is tapped to update the cell appearance which compound your multiple action handler problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-an-element-is-activated/38941510#38941510

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tested the code and the mechanics of it work perfectly but for some reason the image of the button tapped doesn't change

Comment: Also, having two separate but related arrays (products and quantities) is a code smell.   You should use a `orderLineItem` object which has product and quantity properties.

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton`'s `imageView` is read-only — to update its image you should use `setImage`. Note you'll need to keep track of the selection state of the rows or else the selection state will be reset whenever the cell reloads (e.g. it scrolls out and back into view). Also presumably you'll want to handle the case where the button is deselected.

Also, since you're only handling the selection on the `UIButton` in the cell, tapping the cell will not have any effect on the button's state. You could instead implement `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` and handle the selection there, and just have a simple `UIImageView` instead of a `UIButton` in your cell. You could also consider using the [`accessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623219-accessoryview).

`UITableView` also has [built-in support for multiple selection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614938-allowsmultipleselection), so if you turn that on it can keep track of the selected cells for you, and you just need to update the appearance of the cells accordingly.

As for using the `tag` to figure out the cell index, it's true it isn't very robust but that wasn't the question. Definitely worth checking out the linked question in the comments above for some good discussion around that.

And yes, if you're going to stick with this approach you should at least remove any existing actions before adding a new one to avoid duplicate events, e.g. `button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)`.

Comment: How would I keep track of the selection state? Would it be within my ```Itemslected``` func or within the ```cellForRowAt``` func?

Comment: There are various options; You could for example store an `Array` or a `Set` of selected indices in your class and add / remove items upon selection. Or if you went with the `UITableView` approach you could use [`indexPathsForSelectedRows`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows).

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `Product` model is like this.

```
struct Product {
    let name: String
    let photo: UIImage!
    let price: Double
}
```

To keep track of the selected product. You need to preserve the state of the cell. Create another model like this

```
struct ProductSelection {
    let product: Product!
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

As @ Paulw11 mentioned that "`tag` isn't a great solution since the default is 0 and it will break if rows are reordered", you can use delegate pattern to get the selected product index.

Create a protocol of the ProductToBuyCell.

```
protocol ProductToBuyCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func selectedCell(sender: ProductToBuyCell)
}
```

Add a delegate property to cell.

```
weak var delegate: ProductToBuyCellDelegate?
```

Also add an `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` of the button in `ProductToBuyCell`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkButton: UIButton!


@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.selectedCell(sender: self)
}
```

Then add a selectionProduct property in the cell and set text of `UILabel` and image of `UIImage` using property observer `didSet`

```
var productSelection: ProductSelection? {
    didSet {
        guard let productSelection = productSelection else { return }

        self.productNameLabel.text = productSelection.product.name
        self.priceLabel.text = "$\(productSelection.product.price)"
        self.productImg.image = productSelection.product.photo
        
        if productSelection.isSelected {
            checkButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            checkButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "circle"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the appearence of `UIImage` in `awakeFromNib()` method

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    self.productImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

Then modify the `cellForRowAt` method like below. Here, `productSelectionArray` is an array of `ProductSection` not `Product`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductToBuyCell") as! ProductToBuyCell
    cell.productSelection = productSelectionArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Now confirm the `delegate` of `ProductToBuyCell` to `ViewController`. Here, at first I change the state of the selected cell and then retrieve all the selected products using `filter` and `map` function in `productSelectionArray`. And then reload the row to update UI.

```
extension ViewController: ProductToBuyCellDelegate {
    func selectedCell(sender: ProductToBuyCell) {
        guard let tappedIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender) else { return }

        productSelectionArray[tappedIndexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()

        let selectedProducts = productSelectionArray.filter{ $0.isSelected }.map { (productSelection: ProductSelection) -> Product in
            return productSelection.product
        }

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [tappedIndexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

According to your UI it seems that all the selected products quantity is one, so you don't have to maintain another array for quantity.