# Identifying UIButton within UITableViewCell not working - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to identify a cell index by the button that is pressed within the cell. After this has been done, i am trying to pass the information on to another viewController

The original post can be found here:
[detecting uibutton pressed in tableview: Swift Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429652/detecting-uibutton-pressed-in-tableview-swift-best-practices)

My code currently looks like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! questionCell

    //indicates which button was pressed
    myCell.button.tag = indexPath.row
    myCell.button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return myCell
}

var selectedRow = Int()

//sets selected row variable to the row that was selected
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {

    selectedRow = sender.tag
}

//sets the id of the question that was selected in the answers view controller
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

var destinationView: AFeedTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AFeedTableViewController

    destinationView.currentQuestionId = idResults[selectedRow]
}
```

My issue is that the prepareForSegue function is called before the buttonClicked function, and therefore no update is being made to the value i am passing on to the other view controller. Can anyone explain how to resolve this?
Thanks

EDIT: When the button is clicked, a segue is performed

Comment: Is your segue wired up to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your segue is hooked up to the button you don't need the extra target. You can reach the button via the sender object from `prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    guard let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? AFeedTableViewController else { return }

    destinationViewController.currentQuestionId = idResults[button.tag]
}
```