# Swift 3: How do I tap a button inside cell and pass in that indexPath of that cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am doing everything **programatically**, avoiding **storyboards**. I have a collectionView, a `Post` model object that holds a username and password and of course I have collectionView cells. I the issue I am having is that I have a button inside of my collectionView Cells. I want to be able to tap this button and segue into a new controller. This is the easy part. The problem is that I want to not only segue into the new controller but also pass in the specific username of that specific Post Cell of the button I tapped. I hope this makes sense. Basically I want to have a Post, just like any social media application and I want to segue to a "profile" and also pass in the username of that specific user to that profile controller too. I hope you can understand this. Any help will be highly, highly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for some time. I will of course mark as answer. Thank you guys...

```
class MyController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var posts = [Post]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]
    cell.homeController = self

    return cell
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var homeController: MyController?

    var post: Post? {
        didSet {
            if let username = post?.username {
                usernameLabel.text = username
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .blue
        setupViews()
    }

    lazy var myButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        btn.setTitle("Push", for: .normal)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }()

    func handleTapped() {
        let postController = PostController()
        homeController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(postController, animated: true)
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(myButton)

        myButton.frame = CGRect(x: (self.frame.width / 2) - 25, y: (self.frame.height / 2) - 25, width: 50, height: 50)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429652/detecting-uibutton-pressed-in-tableview-swift-best-practices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you to tell your `UIViewController` that a button inside your `CustomCell` has been clicked. You can add a protocol, add a `delegate` property to your cell and then `MyController` has to conform to the protocol. The function should also pass in the cell that has been clicked and you can get the `indexPath` of that cell from your `collectionView`.

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func didSelectButton(in cell: CustomCell)
}

class CustomClass: UICollectionViewClass {
    weak var delegate: CustomCelLDelegate?
    func handleTapped() {
        delegate?.didSelectButton(in: self)
    }
}
```

Then in your `MyController` class, add the delegate and conform to the protocol.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}

extension MyController: CustomCellDelegate {
    func didSelectButton(in cell: CustomCell) {
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            let postController = PostController()
            let post = posts[indexPath.row]
            postController.post = post //pass the data
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(postController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add a `post` variable to your `PostController`.

```
class PostController {
    var post: Post!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the segue instead of that you have pushed the ViewController using the `navigationController`. So pass the value with the `postController` object.

```
func handleTapped() {
    let postController = PostController()
    //Pass the detail that you want
    postController.selectedPost = self.post
    homeController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(postController, animated: true)
}
```

Now in `PostController` declare one instance property of type `Post` with name `selectedPost` and then use that object in `viewDidLoad` to assign your `Labels`.

```
class PostController: UIViewController {
    var selectedPost: Post?

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.yourLabel.text = self.selectedPost.username
    }
```