# Tell to a button which row of the tableView we are tapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello in my tableView i added a refresh button to my custom tableViewCell

[image]

because i want to reload the single cell after the button tap, to do it (looking around the net) i created this func

```
 @IBAction func rowReload(_ sender: Any) {

        let index = IndexPath(row: , section: )
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
    }
```

but my problem is this line `let index = IndexPath(row: , section: )`, how can i tell to my function that the reload action must take place on the row where i pressed the button? (in simple words, what i have to write next `row:` and `section:` ?)

Comment: Do your tableview have multiple sections?

Comment: no only one section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detecting uibutton pressed in tableview: Swift Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429652/detecting-uibutton-pressed-in-tableview-swift-best-practices)

Comment: Check this answer. it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274863/5051255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForRow` method assign tag to a button like shown below:

```
yourCell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then assign selector to it in `cellForRow` method.

```
yourCell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClass.rowReload(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And in your `rowReload` method argument `sender` should have type `UIButton` and your method will be:

```
func rowReload(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

then you can access its tag and your `IndexPath` will be:

```
let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
```

Comment: ok but i have to add @IBOutlet weak var refButton: UIButton! in my controller or in my custom tableViewCell class?

Comment: it should be in custom tableViewCell.

Comment: Then you can it this way: http://ioscake.com/detect-button-click-in-table-view-ios-xcode-for-multiple-row-and-section.html

Answer (score 0):

In your method,

```
> "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
> IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell"
```

you can give the tag number to the element (button)
Eg.

> cell.button.tag = indexPath

So, when you tap on the button, you can get the tag as its indexPath.

> @IBAction func rowReload(_ sender: Any) {
>
> ```
>     let index = sender.tag
>     self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple sections in UITableview then we cannot use tags to determine the indexpath.

```
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```