# Move to another viewcontroller from button action of a custom tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, navigation

I have a button inside  a custom tableview cell in a tableview.
I tried presenting, pushing and instantiating to another view controller but failed by showing error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional

Here s my code:
        [console image if required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DHPl.png)

```
class ProfileHeaderView: UITableViewCell{

    @IBAction func editProfile(_ sender: Any) {

        let editProfilePage = EditProfileViewController()
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(editProfilePage, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } 

}
```

The page which i wanted to move:

```
class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

        mobileNumber.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad **//Error**
    }
}
```

I tried presenting by `rootViewController` also. Please help.

[Screenshot if required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5D5Z.png)

[Updated console after the story board identifier change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKHOy.png)

Comment: possible duplicate: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27429652/5567142)

Comment: have you tried to show that view controller at all? to test if the issue is related to the tableView or it is an issue with the `EditProfileViewController` only

Comment: @Milan Nosal.I hope it it is a issue with EditProfileViewcontroller. But why it says those numpad is nil while it was working fine while navigation from slidemenucontroller.

Comment: @NiranjanB I believe I figured out what's wrong, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EXPLANATION**

The crash is caused by line `mobileNumber.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad` not because of `UIKeyboardType.numberPad`, but rather because of left hand side: `mobileNumber.keyboardType`. Mobile number is supposed to be an `@IBOutlet` of type `UITextField!` (implicitly forced unwrapped `UITextField`), which causes a crash when `mobileNumber` is nil. And that is your case.

It was working before, because before you were using a segue to navigate to `EditProfileViewController` and so storyboards initialized `mobileNumber` field properly before `viewDidLoad` was called. However, you are creating an instance of `EditProfileViewController` programmatically on this line: `let editProfilePage = EditProfileViewController()`, which totally circumvents storyboards. Therefore fields and actions that should be wired up by storyboards will not get wired up, resulting in your crash.

**SOLUTION**

Instead of calling an initializer, use storyboards to create an instance of `EditProfileViewController`. That means, replace this line:

```
let editProfilePage = EditProfileViewController()
```

With something like this:

```
let editProfilePage = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditProfileViewController") as! EditProfileViewController
```

In this line I assume that the storyboard with `EditProfileViewController` is named `Main` (of course, if the `EditProfileViewController` is defined in other storyboard, use that and not the `Main` storyboard there), plus make sure that you use Storyboard ID in your storyboard and it is set to EditProfileViewController (or use any custom id you want):

[image: Setting storyboard ID]

Comment: I tried this also. But showing error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

Comment: @NiranjanB but the error changed, so i believe we are onto something... can you share the whole new message + stacktrace?

Comment: Thats the complete message after this app hangs there itself.

Comment: @NiranjanB how about a screenshot of the xcode at that moment?

Comment: Couldnt add a image to comments section , may i know how ?

Comment: @NiranjanB either upload it somewhere and provide just link, or add it to the question

Comment: @NiranjanB see the bottom part of the updated answer and try to use it instead, and then show me the console output

Comment: TrackAction: left tap open.
>> begin
>> storyboard: <UIStoryboard: 0x604000660c80>
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) ..

Comment: @NiranjanB OK, from this I would assume that there is no view controller with storyboard ID = `"EditProfileViewController"` in Main storyboard. 1. check that you are using a correct storyboard - is the `EditProfileViewController` in `Main` or in other? If in other, change storyboard creation to `UIStoryboard(name: "otherStoryboard", bundle: nil)`, if that's not the case, 2. Make sure that you really set the storyboard ID to `"EditProfileViewController"`

Comment: Nosal. Sorry, that was a mistake, but i changed the identifer, now app is not crashing but at the same time, its not navigating. i have shared the console window.

Comment: @NiranjanB because you are not presenting it, just creating it.. add the last line: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(editProfilePage, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much, Thank you especially for your patient guidance. Im marking this as Correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for myself with the following code
You can use a protocol to delegate the click inside the tableviewcell back to the UIViewController
In my case I did use segues but you can instantiate your `EditProfileViewController` directly inside the `cellCallback` function

Code for the delegate

```
protocol CellDelegator {
    func cellCallback(myData dataobject: Item)
}
```

Code inside the tableview cell

```
@IBAction func imageClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.cellCallback(myData: (self.cartItem?.item)!)

}
```

Code inside the ViewController

```
extension MyViewController :  CellDelegator{
    func cellCallback(myData dataobject: Item) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "xyz", sender: dataobject)
    }
```