# how to get the value of textfield in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I have a two class. Whenever I get the value of the textfield it prints nothing and if I get rid of unwrap symbol it prints optional(""). How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
class userRegistration: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // in faction cell for item at index path i have this code
    function collectionView(..){
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath) as! registerNewUser

        cell.registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    @objc func click()        
    {
        let object = registerNewUser()
        let email = object.newEmailTextField.text!

        print(email)
    }
}
```

This is done programmatically and in Swift 4.

Comment: Your question is so far from what you need to do that I'm not sure how to help you. What is `registerNewUser()`. Is that an initializer of a class? Is that an instance method? How is that supposed to be getting access to a text field in your cell? You should probably implement the collection  view delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` instead of trying to figure out which cell was tapped and get it's indexPath.

Comment: registerNewUser is a class

Comment: Ok, so the construct `registerNewUser()` creates a brand new instance of that class. (Class names should start with an upper-case letter BTW.) How could this newly created object possibly contain a text field with your input in it?

Comment: thank you for correcting me for the naming of class im just new in swift. thats my problem i cant get the value is their any ways that i can get the data from registerNewUser class

Comment: The expression `registerNewUser()` is creating a new instance of your `registerNewUser` (which should be `RegisterNewUser`) class. Instead, you need to save your `registerNewUser` object in an instance variable in your view controller somewhere. You are making so many mistakes I can tell you are trying to do too much too soon. You need to back off a bit and do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take `Indexpath` which `item` you are clicking `Register` `Button`.

```
@objc func click(sender: UIButton)        
{

    let cellPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: collexnVw)
    let indPath : IndexPath = collexnVw.indexPathForItem(at: cellPosition!)!

    let cell = collxnVw.cellForItem(at: indPath) as! registerNewUser 

    let email = cell.newEmailTextField.text!

    print(email)
}
```

You may get some reference from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429652/detecting-uibutton-pressed-in-tableview-swift-best-practices)