# TableView with custom cell button, indexpath

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I have a tableview with a custom cell that include a button, this button should delete the entry (and reload the tableview) after it been hit.

So i m looking for a way to get the index path of the cell from the botton?

Comment: You can add a tag to the `UIButton` and then retrieve it?

Comment: did not know about tags :-) thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you can define a tag for your `UIButton`.

Something like

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then when the buttons action is triggered you can get the `indexPath` via `button.tag`.